# Clean & Safe string in PHP

Tags: php, string, code-injection

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [PHP: the ultimate clean/secure function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4223980/php-the-ultimate-clean-secure-function)
>   [What's the best method for sanitizing user input with PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/129677/whats-the-best-method-for-sanitizing-user-input-with-php)

What should I add to my function to be sure that every string that passes it will be 'server-friendly'? I use this small function to check inputs that contains names, e-mail addresses and ids.

```
   function checkInput($str) {
        $str = @strip_tags($str);
        $str = @stripslashes($str);
        $str = mysql_real_escape_string($str);
        return $str;
    }
```

Comment: Agree with Pekka. But to summarize. There is no such thing as what you are trying to do.

Comment: Everything is context sensitive.  It's impossible to have 1 function do it all.  For example, you only want to call a `mysql_real_escape_string` on data that's going into the database.  And you want to call `htmlspecialchars` only on data as its being rendered.  So there's no magic bullet (And there shouldn't be)...

Answer (score 9):

I would remove some special characters thet have nothing to do in such strings and could be used for code injections, like $ % # < > | and so on.

```
$invalid_characters = array("$", "%", "#", "<", ">", "|");
$str = str_replace($invalid_characters, "", $str);
```

Answer (score 4):

> What should I add to my function to be sure that every string that passes it will be 'server-friendly'?

This should work:

```
function checkInput($str) {
  return "";
}
```

For a more detailed explanation, [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/129677/whats-the-best-method-for-sanitizing-user-input-with-php)

Comment: no, it is not, but I giggled :)

Answer (score 3):

What does server friendly mean?

For validation such as email addresses take a look at [data filtering](http://php.net/manual/en/book.filter.php).

To make sure a string is safe for database's use escaping such as `mysql_real_escape_string`

When outputting data use `htmlspecialchars`

Answer (score 0):

About DataBase, check [PDO](http://php.net/manual/fr/book.pdo.php) placeholders. They are cross DBMS.

Comment: and they also provide an abstraction over the database engine running behind