# Prevent html insertion in text php

Tags: php, html

I have an issue  when i enter text i can enter html with the text.For example "I am entering text ". Now this link shows up as a link when the form is submitted. Any ideas on how to prevent this?

```
I am entering text <a href="xyz.com">Go to my site </a>. This is the input so when i output the data it comes out as I am entering text **Go to my site** with the hyperlink.
```

Comment: please elaborate with code examples

Comment: Are you going to show us some code?

Answer (score 6):

Put the string in `htmlspecialchars()` or `strip_tags()`.

And, since I feel cleaning strings for other purposes will be the next question thrown out, I should bring up this: [The ultimate clean/secure function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4223980/php-the-ultimate-clean-secure-function)

Answer (score 2):

You aren't going to easily be able to prevent a user from entering tags without javascript, but you can use

```
 strip_tags()
```

on the backend to remove them.

```
 htmlspecialchars()
```

will not remove these tags, it will just encode the special characters.

Answer (score 0):

Normally, you do not want to *prevent* this. You want to *make sure it doesn't output HTML* when you print it.

The way to do that is like so:

```
echo $_GET['text']; // this prints HTML links etc
echo htmlspecialchars($_GET['text']); // this does not
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, you want to prevent injecting HTML code. Use [`htmlspecialchars()`](http://duckduckgo.com/?q=!php%20htmlspecialchars).

```
echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['myform']);
```

Answer (score 0):

Sanitize your input data before displaying it. This is well knows as a [Cross Site Scripting](http://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-site_Scripting_%28XSS%29) (XSS) attack.
You can use `htmlspecialchars()` or `string_tags()` to clean the data.