# Sanitizing GET/POST using a loop?

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [The ultimate clean/secure function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4223980/the-ultimate-clean-secure-function)

When it comes to sanitizing POST/GET data could we just program a loop to go through all set variables in a universal php include file and never had to worry about it in code?

I have always done a function called sanitize to do this but this seems to make sense.

Comment: There is no such thing like "sanitization". Once you do something you call "sanitization" - you are doing something wrong and making your app vulnerable and/or unusable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be better off creating a function in your application that would do it when needed. Then you'll still have the original posted values in case you need them and you can modify the function as needed based on what youre cleansing by passing it options. For example:

```
function getPostField($field)
{
    // all your sanitation and isset/empty checks
    $val = sanitize($_REQUEST[$field]);
    // ...
    return $val;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, of course. Some frameworks do this automatically and store the sanitized `REQUEST` variables in a different array or object, so the original data is still available should it ever be required.

Comment: Should I have a seperate one for database/non-database?

Comment: I keep all database sanitization in my database class, so data is checked just before insertion/querying.

Comment: PHP had this feature once... it took ages to ban it from the language.