# Trying to stop bullets in textareas from entering my database as special characters

Tags: php, mysql, insert, escaping, special-characters

I am using this currently, but it doesn't seem to be working for bullets:

```
function sanitizeMySQL($var){
        $var = mysql_real_escape_string($var);
        $var = sanitizeString($var);
        return $var;
}

function sanitizeString($var)
{
    $var = str_replace('â€¢','•', $var);
    $var = htmlentities($var);
    $var = strip_tags($var);
    return $var;
}
```

This is what bullets show up like in my db after someone has submitted them through a textarea:

`â€¢`

EDIT: This is now what I am getting: `&acirc;€&cent;`.

I do have bullets stored in my db, so I know it allows them. Is there a correct way to store bullets in latin-1 encoding?

Comment: Are your tables using latin-1 encoding? Because I'm fairly sure the round bullet is a UTF-8 thing.

Comment: This is an encoding problem. What encoding are your pages in, what encoding are you using in the data base? Side note: `strip_tags()` and `htmlentities()` are not necessary for database sanitation, see [The ultimate clean/secure function](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4223980)/

Comment: You should really sanitize the string **before** you escape it. I'm pretty sure JS can be injected trough this and maybe even SQL.

Comment: What encoding are you using in the *page*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data that is submitted through your form and your source code do not have the same encoding. Therefore the `â€¢` characters from your source code do not match the ones in the actual data. Therefore they are not being replaced. Unify on a common encoding. See [Handling Unicode Front To Back In A Web App](http://kunststube.net/frontback/).

Also, your sanitization strategy is pretty weird. I don't know what you have against "â€¢", this should not be replaced in a general "sanitization" function. Furthermore, you're first HTML escaping everything, *then* are stripping tags. Hint: there won't be any tags anymore after you have escaped them. Next, you should not modify the string anymore after you have SQL escaped it. See [The Great Escapism (Or: What You Need To Know To Work With Text Within Text)](http://kunststube.net/escapism/).

Comment: So would you recommend  I change the encoding of either my db or page? Also, I have changed the sanitization function to this: `function sanitizeMySQL($val){
   $val = htmlentities($val);
   $val = strip_tags($val);
   $val = mysql_real_escape_string($val);
   return $val;
 }`

Comment: Again, the encoding of your *source code* and the encoding of the submitted data appear not to match. And `strip_tags` after `htmlentities` is still nonsense, you probably don't need either.

Comment: Is it better to use UTF8 throughout the whole chain?

Comment: My DB has a default of UTF-8_bin now, and the specific columns have been changed for UTF-8, but I still get the same results.

Comment: Read both articles linked in my answer. Then read some more of the articles linked from there.