# SQL Server Bullet Symbol String Interpretation

Tags: php, html, sql-server, textbox, symbols

I'm very confused with the way Chrome->PHP->SQL Server handles a bullet symbol. It appears that a bullet symbol is intrepreted differently among the three and SQL Server fails to INSERT my string containing a bullet symbol.

Say I have a form that has an input textbox field with maxlength='50' and I'm using chrome to fill it out. I fill out the textbox with a string that's up to 49 characters, plus a bullet symbol. Chrome interprets that as 50 characters and allows me to move on; however, when I submit through PHP to execute my INSERT query with a $_POST['string'] explicitly (without any sanitization/truncation/conversion), SQL Server fails.

> SQLSTATE[22001]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL
>   Server]String or binary data would be truncated.

I believe it's due to SQL Server interpreting the bullet as more than one character, as opposed to how Chrome interpreted it. What is good practice or a standard rule of thumb to get around this?

*Note: I'm running PHP 5.4.24 and SQL Server 2008 R2.*

Comment: Ignoring what Chrome thinks for a moment, have you checked on the PHP side (before submitting to the DB) to see what it believes the submitted string length is?

Comment: `maxlength='50'` means up to 50 characters, not 49.

Comment: @RobWilkins I've done a strlen("•") and it appears to count it as 3 characters instead of one. Any way around this or is there some kind of conversion I should consider before I insert it in my database table?

Comment: @theflarenet -- this may be an encoding issue.  I found a similar issue being discussed on Stack, perhaps it will help -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11674531/trying-to-stop-bullets-in-textareas-from-entering-my-database-as-special-charact