# PHP security function

Tags: php

I have make a simple function for security prevent from sql injection and XXS
here is my code, any suggestion for this? Is this good enough for security?

```
function mres($input){
    if(get_magic_quotes_gpc()){
        $input=stripslashes($input);    
    }
    $input=htmlentities($input, ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8');
    return mysql_real_escape_string($input);
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/4223980/285587

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is wrong in at least two ways:

1. Turn of `magic_quotes` completely if you can.  At least you are not using it, but `$input` may not be scalar
2. `htmlentities` is for *display*, not storage.  Never encode for storage!
3. `mysql_*` functions are deprecated.  There is no guarantee you will have an open mysql connection (required) when you call it either.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php

Comment: so is any way to fix this function?

Comment: @chienpinwang no, it's unfixable at this point.  Abandon it and all of its contents.  Start using `PDO`.

Answer (score 0):

Look what you're actually doing:

Magic quotes is a bulk escaping of all incoming data, which makes you vulnerable, as escaping alone doesn't make your data "safe" by any means.

So, you are cleaning these bulk escapes... and then apply the very same escaping again :)

Comment: Not exactly .. `mysql_real_escape_string` and `addslashes` are not equivalent.  Plus `htmlentities` encodes quotes that would be escaped.