# PHP - Issues removing "\r\n\r\n" from this string: "I would like to:\r\n\r\n1.) Rid this mess\r\n\r\n\2.) Now Please"

Tags: php, preg-replace, str-replace

I start out with a string like this : "I would like to:\r\n\r\n1.) Rid this mess\r\n\r\n\2.) Now Please" (this is 'cleaned' user input text).

So essentially my statement would be this :

```
$query = sanitize($_POST['query']); // gives the result string
```

I want to remove the "\r\n\r\n"'s from this string. So far I have try to do this by using the following :

```
$query = preg_replace("/\r\n\r\n/", " ", $query);
```

or

```
$query = str_replace("\r\n\r\n", " ", $query);
```

None seem to work?

However, if I do the following :

```
$query = "I would like to:\r\n\r\n1.) Rid this mess\r\n\r\n\2.) Now Please";
$query = preg_replace("/\r\n\r\n/", " ", $query); // I tried str_replace() too
var_dump($query);
exit;
```

I get the output that I desire...

Could someone please explain to me why on earth this is happening and how i could solve the issue?

Any advice, input or suggestions would be greatly appreciated as I am not almost bald from pulling my hair out...

Thank you!

EDIT :

This may help function sanitize() :

```
function html($text)
{
    return htmlspecialchars($text, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
}

function htmlout($text)
{
    return html($text);
}

function cleanInput($input)
{
    $search = array(
        '@<script[^>]*?>.*?</script>@si',   // Strip out javascript
        '@<[\/\!]*?[^<>]*?>@si',            // Strip out HTML tags
        '@<style[^>]*?>.*?</style>@siU',    // Strip style tags properly
        '@<![\s\S]*?--[ \t\n\r]*>@'         // Strip multi-line comments
    );
    $output = preg_replace($search, '', $input);
    $output  = htmlout($output);
    return $output;
}

function sanitize($input)
{
    if (is_array($input))
    {
        foreach($input as $var=>$val)
        {
            $output[$var] = sanitize($val);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        include "C:/wamp/www/includes/inc/main/db.inc.php";
        if (get_magic_quotes_gpc())
        {
            $input = stripslashes($input);
        }
        $input  = cleanInput($input);
        $output = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $input);
    }
    return $output;
}
```

Comment: Are we talking about line feeds or `\r\n` literal characters?

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario This is the result of removing a line break from some user input text. I assume that the translation in this results results in literal characters as this is what gets stored in my database. I will post the sanitize() code in a second...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Difference between single quote and double quote string in php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446216/difference-between-single-quote-and-double-quote-string-in-php)

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario I don't see how that really relates to my question at all...

Comment: If you want to strip literal `\r\n\r\n` characters `str_replace("\r\n\r\n", " ", $query)` will fail to do it because of such difference.

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario I understand this more clearly now, thank you for your input, i shall read through that question thoroughly!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## The only proper solution

1. Get rid of `sanitize()` function
2. Use prepared statements to put your data into database.
3. use `htmlout()` function to display user's text back.

You can read more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4223980/the-ultimate-clean-secure-function) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: I have always used prepared statements but never really considered the fact that what i was doing was a double job :s I guess i have taught myself something irrelevant ... Although, i do use the function sometimes when text is redisplayed to the user, e.g. in an error situation where "your input of : etc... is invalid"... This would be the correct use for something like that right? In any case, i really appreciate your reply, i think i should put a lot more thought into that!!

Comment: You have an outstanding name too! hehe :)

Comment: What would happen if a user purposefully intended to post malicious code, would it not be better to use something like the cleanInput() function instead of just htmlout()?

Answer (score 1):

Have you got magic quotes on?

http://php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.magic-quotes-gpc

It might be escaping your slashes.

Answer (score 0):

If there's literal `\r\n` characters in your database, you need to quadruple the slashes.

So you using this should in theory do the trick:

```
$query = preg_replace("/\\\\r\\\\n\\\\r\\\\n", " ", $query);
```

Comment: Okay i think i kind of understand now... In my database it gets stored at "\r\n\r\n" and this is the exact output of the text once it has been 'cleaned'... So you're saying I should be escaping the slashes? B.T.W. Not trying to be a stickler but you missed the trailing / :) I'll give it a try and post the result, thanks so much!

Comment: You need four slashes because you are using two contexts where `\r\n` has a special meaning: double-quoted strings and regular expressions. You don't really need any of those here.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
$string = preg_replace("/\\\\r\\\\n\\\\r\\\\n/", "", $string);
```