# PHP|MySQLi : Using ..real_escape.. with exact parameters?

Tags: php, mysqli

I was wondering if i should still use mysqli_real_escape_string in this situation

I have a set list of url parameters that are accepted otherwise they are ignored.

```
if(isset($_GET["data"])) {  
  $data = $_GET["data"]; 
  switch($data) { 
    case "one" :
      //do x
      $sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE page='".$data."'";
    break;
    case "two" :
      //do x
    break;
    case "three" :
      //do x
    break;
  }
}
```

Comment: you are not passing anything except known strings to the query. you can safely avoid escaping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, mysqli_real_escape_string isn't needed.  The purpose of this function is to "sanitize" data that is input by a user.

In your code as it currently is written, yes, you are using data input by a user in that $_GET['data'] may contain something input into a form (or likewise); however, since you are then using a switch statement to check $_GET['data'] *before* you concatenate it to a query, you are a-okay.

However, if you decide to implement a "default case" that concatenates $data to a query without first comparing it to a value you know to be safe, then, yes, you should sanitize your data.

Here's some further reading on sanitizing your user input: [The ultimate clean/secure function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4223980/the-ultimate-clean-secure-function)