# Cannot determine INSERT PDO error. SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, syntax-error, sql-insert

I'm trying to execute an SQL INSERT but I am getting the error:

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'key) VALUES (example@example.com, hello)' at line 1

The values in the table are: id(auto increment), email and key which are both varchar(255) with the id being (int).

```
function validate($data)
{
    $data = trim($data);
    $data = stripslashes($data);
    $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
    return $data;
}

$key = 'hello';
$email = validate($_POST['email']);

$insert = $user->recordPasswordReset($email, $key);


public function recordPasswordReset($email, $key)
{
    try 
    {
        $db = DB();
        $sql = "INSERT INTO password_reset(email, key) VALUES (:email, :key)";
        $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->bindParam(':email', $email, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(':key', $key, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->execute();
    } 
    catch (PDOException $e) 
    {
        echo ($e->getMessage());
    }
}
```

Can anybody see any errors in my code?

Comment: Get rid of that "validate" function. [You shouldn't be using a all-in-one sanitize function.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4223980/the-ultimate-clean-secure-function)

Comment: You are using visibility keywords outside of a class?

Comment: You could have Google'd the error.

Answer (score 1):

**Firstly**, as per the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html), your field name `key` is a reserved keyword. You need to use back ticks around it.

Change,

```
INSERT INTO password_reset(email, key) VALUES (:email, :key)
```

To,

```
INSERT INTO password_reset(email, `key`) VALUES (:email, :key)
```

**Secondly**, please don't use an [all-in-one sanitize function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4223980/the-ultimate-clean-secure-function) as they generally have some form of flaw in them.

**Thirdly**, you are using visibility keywords outside of a class.