# PHP post error Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, post

I am trying to post data to my database using the following code:

```
 <?php
if(isset($_POST['add']))
{
$dbhost = 'internal-db';
$dbuser = 'support';
$dbpass = 'sgh';
$db = "mpc";
$conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
if(! $conn )
{
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

$firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
$surname = $_POST['surname'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$country = $_POST['country'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$callback = $_POST['callback'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO enquiries 
       (firstname, surname, email, phone, country, message, callback)
       VALUES('$firstname','$surname', $email, $phone, $country, $message, $callback)";

mysql_select_db($db);
$retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );
if(! $retval )
{
  die('Could not enter data: ' . mysql_error());
}
echo "Entered data successfully\n";
mysql_close($conn);
}
else
{
?>
```

When I try to post the form I revieve the following error:

```
Could not enter data: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ' , , , )' at line 3
```

Can't work out what is wrong in the code. Can you help???? Am I using deprecated code??

Comment: Think: what would happen of some of your variables were empty? Now think, what would happen if a variable would be `'); DROP table enquiries; --`? Don't construct SQL statement for strings, use prepared statements and check your user input!

Answer (score 1):

The `variables` in your query are empty `($email, $phone, $country, $message, $call)`. Try to do `var_dump` of the variables before the `query` and see if they have some `value`. Also you need to wrap them with quotes like `'$var'` when they are strings, such as a mail.

**Also, for the love of god, sanitize the input. See here:**

[What are the best PHP input sanitizing functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3126072/what-are-the-best-php-input-sanitizing-functions)

[How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-stop-sql-injection-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

You have to put the single quote around the string columns even if they are blank or contain value.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO enquiries 
       (firstname, surname, email, phone, country, message, callback)
       VALUES('$firstname','$surname', '$email', '$phone', '$country', '$message', '$callback')";
```

Do not forgot to use [mysql_real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) on the data.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't encapsulated your fields in quotes. E-mail address (amongst others) without quotes will make your INSERT statement invalid.

Besides that, you should *always* escape the input, because the input can contain invalid characters, or worse, it can contain malicious code that may destroy your data!

So:

```
if (array_key_exists($_POST, 'email')) {
  $tmpemail = (string)$_POST['email']; 
  // Optional additional checks for pattern matches go here..
  // if all tests succeed, escape special characters and assign value:
  $email = mysql_real_escape_string($tmpemail);
}
// Similar checks for other values

if ((isset($email) && isset($fielda) && isset($fieldb) ... )
{
  $query = "
      INSERT INTO YourTable(fielda, fieldb, email, ...)
      VALUES('valuea', 'valueb', '$email', ...)";
}
else
{
  // Some values missing. Handle appropriately.
}
```