# would null byte injection affect me if I was using a $_GET variable to make MYSQL query?

Tags: php, mysql, security, get

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are the best PHP input sanitizing functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3126072/what-are-the-best-php-input-sanitizing-functions)

Let's say I have a `$_GET` variable with the name "id". The `$_GET` variable is then used in a mysql query to retrieve some data like `SELECT text FROM database WHERE id=$_GET['id'];`
Would null byte injection in my `$_GET` variable affect me assuming I'm using common security functions like `mysql_real_escape_string()`, `addslashes()`, and `strip_tags()`?

Comment: Assuming you're not using them wrong, like your question suggests, that wouldn't be a problem for string literals in your query.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Would null byte injection in my $_GET variable affect me assuming I'm using common security functions like mysql_real_escape_string(), addslashes(), and strip_tags()?

Probably not, but a much more simple injection *would* affect you. Try passing this as the GET parameter:

```
99999 OR id=0
```

and run it through the query you show above. It will allow injection of arbitrary SQL **even when using** `mysql_real_escape_string`.

Contrary to popular belief, `mysql_real_escape_string()` will **not** protect you if your value is not enclosed in quotes.

If querying for numeric values, either test whether it's a number before inserting the value into the string, or put the value into quotes:

```
 $id = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET["id"]);
 $query = "SELECT text FROM database WHERE id='$id'";
```

`addslashes` and `strip_tags` have no value at all in this context. They only serve to break data, but they add no security when inserting stuff in a database. Just get rid of them. (`strip_tags` may be appropriate later when you output something on a HTML page.)