# How to hide URL using php or javascript

Tags: javascript, php

Here is what Adel Agoudjil asked time ago.  I have the same question.  Anyone can give a straight answer, please?

"I want to know how to encrypt the URL on Apache/PHP?

For example:
**www.example.com/how-to-encrypt.html**

to
**www.example.com/DMQRzZWMDdGQtbndzBHNsawN0aXRsZQR0ZXN0AzcwMQR3b2UDMjQwMjEwNQ**

I want to know how to do like this, is it through JavaScript/PHP/Apache?"

Comment: Are you asking how to configure the server to accept the encrypted url and realize that it needs to serve "how-to-encrypt.html"?  That would be Apache's mod_rewrite and some clever coding.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Encrypt the URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9542610/how-to-encrypt-the-url)

Comment: You can use php to make and verify password hash to identify page name and then use include that file.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can write a single main.php page:

**www.example.com/main.php?p=DMQRzZWMDdGQtbndzBHNsawN0aXRsZQR0ZXN0AzcwMQR3b2UDMjQwMjEwNQ**

Then decrypt text and redirect to where you want.

But I am not sure this method works or not.