# Making $_POST data safe to email

Tags: php, email

I understand about `mysql_real_escape_string` and such, But what about when i am just sending an email?

So I have form, and a textbox, is there any vulnerabilities in just directly emailing the `$_POST` data to a user? I guess they wouldnt be able to execute any PHP.. or can they if they run it from a web address? I am not sure.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What are the best PHP input sanitizing functions?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3126072/what-are-the-best-php-input-sanitizing-functions)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If it is being sent directly to an email then it will be fine. If it is being stored in a database to be displayed on an administrator page such as a helpdesk, etc. then it will need to be escaped for both html output and mysql. You can escape mysql using a number of functions:

- If using PDO then use prepare statement :
  http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php
- Otherwise I would use :
  http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php

That said because Emails can contain HTML, if you don't want to receive emails that people have put bogus HTML in such as `<blink>` (Which is really annoying) then you can use `htmlspecialchars()` : http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php

If you are worried about Javascript in emails then using `htmlspecialchars()` noted above will escape this also.

Comment: Don't forget JavaScript which can be put into e-mails, too. It might sound like bad joke, but some clients support this, e.g. Thunderbird.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is **don't trust a user input**. The biggest problem is, when you set the Email adress or BCC from your **POST** variable. That any email address can be set over the Request.

But its possible to send links or something else to user over your form. For this you should implement a captcha. That a bot cannot send your form with defined values to anyone.

A last solution is a hidden text field in your form. You can hide them with CSS. When the field is not empty you know that a bot has filled them.

But i think its good when you escape your POST vars with [htmlspecialchars()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php)

So there are a lot of possibilities to secure a form. You should use not only one of them and trust the user.