# mysql_real_escape_string during retrieval

Tags: php, mysql

I've used `mysql_real_escape_string()` to sanitise data when inserting it into the database, is it okay to use it again when retrieving data from the database?

Comment: If you're attempting to reverse the escaping for display purposes, try `stripslashes()`.

Comment: does it mean that if I store something like //name> it would be returned as name?

Comment: @showdev `stripslashes()` only needs to be used on input data from forms if you can't turn off magic quotes in your PHP isntance.

Comment: You're doing it wrong! You should not be using `ext/mysql`. Instead use PDO or mysqli.

Comment: @staticsan Not exactly true -- there are other uses. I have used stripslashes() in the past (with old mysql_* code) to remove escaping from data pulled from the database. Otherwise it can be displayed with slashes.

Comment: @showdev For old data and old code that had escaping problems, yes, I agree.

Comment: If you're asking this many questions about SQL escaping, you should probably use a [PHP framework](http://www.phpframeworks.com/top-10-php-frameworks/) that can do it for you.

Answer (score 3):

It's not ok to use it at any time. The MySQL extension has been deprecated. Use PDO or MySQLi instead.

When using data in a query, use parameter binding instead of string manipulation for sanitising purposes.

You do not need to sanitise data on retrieval. If you're displaying the data in an HTML page, use the `htmlspecialchars()` or `htmlentities()` functions instead.

### Update

To explain, you should not be storing data with escape characters in it. The best approach is to store data as received without modification (this is external to any validation you use to filter inputs prior to storing).

PDO and MySQLi both support parameter binding which is the safest way to store volatile data, eg (PDO)

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO tableName VALUES (:param1, :param2)');
$stmt->bindParam('param1', $var1);
$stmt->bindParam('param2', $var2);
$stmt->execute();
```

Upon retrieval, you will receive the data as it went in so you do not need to modify it again.

To safely display this data in an HTML page, use one of the encoding functions listed above, eg

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT name FROM tableName');
$stmt->execute();

$row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
?>

<p>Hello, <?= htmlspecialchars($row['name']) ?></p>
```

Comment: Arrrggghhh the `stripslashes()` recommendations are hurting my eyes!

Comment: wow, useful information thanks, it sure helped

Comment: Good advice, Phil. My suggestion assumes (as the OP suggested) that `mysql_real_escape_string()` is already being used. stripslashes is not depreciated...

Comment: @showdev I never said `stripslashes()` was deprecated. In any case, it's only use is to undo magic quotes (which shouldn't be enabled anyway) or reverse `addslashes()`. It should not be used around query parameters at all

Comment: @Phil I believe the OP was asking about escpaing data coming out of the database. The issue of which function to use for escaping is a secondary issue.

Comment: @Phil I didn't mean to suggest that you said stripslashes() is depreciated. I was referring more to Blowski's comment. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 2):

**No**, `mysql_real_escape_string()` (and it's more modern version `mysqli::real_escape_string()`) should not be used on data *retrieved* from the database.

The only reason for escaping data for *insertion* into the database is because you are assembling it as string-data in another language: SQL. That is the purpose of escaping. If there was an API call where you provided all the elements as discrete parameters, you would not need to escape the data. But that's not how SQL works.

(Similarly, `stripslashes()` is only needed if you can't turn off magic quotes in your PHP instance.)

Comment: If you can't turn off magic quotes, host your application somewhere else. Having it on is insane.

Answer (score -2):

Yes always.

```
    $username = stripslashes($_POST['username']);
    $username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']); 
    $password = mysql_real_escape_string(md5($_POST['password']));//with md5
    And retrieve----
    $req = mysql_query('select password,id from users where username="'.$username.'"');
    $dn = mysql_fetch_array($req);
    if($dn['password']==md5($password) and mysql_num_rows($req)>0)
{ // ...
```

The reason you want to sanitize on retrieval is that most injections happen here. Case in point Facebook's hack from a user a year ago--he submitted a mysql_query retrieval into the browser to fetch another users data. And wound up inside the admin's program.

Comment: The `mysql_*` functions should not be used in any new code for any reason.

Comment: md5'd passwords should not be used in any new code for any reason.

Comment: @Charles Suggesting to use SHA1 instead?

Comment: so I sanitize on insertion and again on retrieval?

Comment: @showdev, no, bcrypt as provided by [`crypt`](http://php.net/crypt) in `$2y$` mode with a high cost.

Comment: @user1938257, no.  Validate and filter on input.  SQL escape on insert.  Optional escape on output depending on how you do filtering.  [See previous answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3126175/168868).

Comment: May try sha512 too. Charles is right here. Many injections can use md5 which can be a threat. Use a $hash salt along with either one--$salt=fGMNIub43kJHb5T6kl; Then add it to all retrieved data  etc . --$user=mysql_real_escape_string(sha1($_POST['password'] + $salt))

Comment: You do [SQL escaping](http://bobby-tables.com/php) on *any* and *all* things going into a query. You do HTML escaping on anything rendered in an HTML context. You **do not** use SQL escaping functions unless you're putting data into a database. Period. Your use of `stripslashes` here suggests this code only works in a recklessly misconfigured PHP environment.