# Validate text Area

Tags: java, regex

I am creating and Activity and I need to validate the correct input type in a Text Area. I want to avoid any XSS or Mysql Injection.

I want to accept [a-z] [A-Z] [0-9] [.] [,] and whitespace.

The only thing that I got by now is:

```
Pattern pattern_ = Pattern.compile("^[:alpha:]+(?:(?:\\s+|-)[:alpha:]+)*$");
```

How would you implement that?

Comment: What language are using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Exactly what you asked for

If you only want to accept exactly the characters `[a-z]`, `[A-Z]`, `[0-9]`, `.`, and `,`, the most direct way of doing that is to match the regular expression `^[a-zA-Z0-9.,\s]*$`. (See this on [Regexr](http://regexr.com?36fqe).)

#### Why that's not a good idea

Depending on the data, severely restricting the input like this is not a good idea.

If your data entry field is for people's names, it won't allow people to enter names with accented characters, or names in languages other than English. `Thévenin` (a French name) would be out because it contains an accented `é`. The Chinese family name `伟` would also be illegal. The Greek name `Αφρουδάκης` would be entirely illegal.

#### What you should do instead

Your language should have ways of **sanitizing input data**. These will prevent SQL or XSS attacks without prohibiting otherwise harmless data like `伟`. Refer to this question for a general overview of input sanitization: [What are the best PHP input sanitizing functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3126072/what-are-the-best-php-input-sanitizing-functions)

Answer (score 1):

Why don't just do this:

```
Pattern pattern_ = Pattern.compile("^[a-zA-Z0-9\.,\s]+$");
```