# Using lower MySQL method POST?

Tags: php, mysql

need to record all information in lower case in the database.
How to do this with mysql?

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO event (codigo_stm,playlist,startdate,starttime,repeatc,priority,loopatend,enddate,shuffle) VALUES ('".$dados_stm["codigo"]."','".$_POST["playlist"]."','".$_POST["data"]."".$data2."' ,'".$_POST["hora"].":".$_POST["minuto"].":00' ,'".$_POST["repeatc"]."' ,'1','1','".$_POST["data_fim"]."','".$_POST["shuffle"]."')");
```

What PHP or database function do I use to insert lowercase into the database?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Declare a variable before inserting the value to the DB. In here you can do some operations like:

`$data = strtolower($_POST['data']);`

Plus use some sanitation methods.
[What are the best PHP input sanitizing functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3126072/what-are-the-best-php-input-sanitizing-functions)

Or prepare statements. http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php
You should never trust the user input!.

You can do it with MySQL using the function LOWER. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_lower

Answer (score 2):

Before passing your values to mysql lower your string by function given below.

$xyz=strtolower($str);

Answer (score 2):

Just use the php `strtolower` function.

```
$str "HelLo WoRlD";
$str = strtolower($str);
echo $str; //echos "hello world"
```

[PHP manual strtolower function](https://www.php.net/strtolower)

Comment: And please, please, please escape your input so you don't get a SQL injection... so `mysql_real_escape_string(strtolower($_POST["playlist"]))` for each one...

Comment: I think everyone needs to know the tale of [Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [LOWER](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_lower) in mysql

```
INSERT INTO your_table (name, language)
VALUES ( "Some Name", LOWER( "SOME VALUE" ) );
```

Another option is use [strtolower](https://www.php.net/strtolower) in php

Side Note: [Why shouldn't I use mysql_* functions in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php)

Answer (score 1):

In PHP - Use [`strtolower`](https://www.php.net/strtolower) for any string you want in lowercase only.

In MySQL - Use [`LOWER`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_lower), although doing it in PHP makes much more sense.

A side note - Make sure you [sanitize your inputs](http://www.dreamhost.com/dreamscape/2013/05/29/part-2-of-php-security-user-validation-and-sanitization-for-beginners/) and name your child [`Robert'); DROP TABLE students;--`](http://www.explainxkcd.com/wiki/index.php/Little_Bobby_Tables).