# Query outputs php code

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm following a book about PhP and MySQL but the following code doesn't work properly:

```
<html>
    <head>
    <title>Book-O-Rama Search Results</title>
    </head>
<body>
<h1>Book-O-Rama Search Results</h1>
<?php
//short variables
$searchtype = $_POST['searchtype'];
$searchterm = trim($_POST['searchterm']);

echo $searchterm;

if(!$searchtype || !$searchterm) {
    echo 'You have not entered search details.';
    exit;
}

if(!get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
    $searchtype = addslashes($searchtype);
    $searchterm = addslashes($searchterm);
}

@ $db = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'books');

if(mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo 'Error: could not connect to the database. Please try again later.';
    exit;
} else {
    echo "All right";
}

$query = "select * from books where ".$searchtype." like '%".$searchterm."%";
$result = $db->query($query);

$num_results = $result->num_rows;

echo "<p>Number of books found: ".$num_results."</p>";

for($i=0; $i < $num_results; $i++) {
    $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
    echo "<p><strong>".($i+1).". Title: ";
    echo htmlspecialchars(stripslashes($row['title']));
    echo"</strong><br />Author: ";
    echo stripslashes($row['author']);
    echo "<br /> ISBN: ";
    echo stripslashes($row['isbn']);
    echo "<br />Price: ";
    echo stripslashes($row['price']);
    echo "</p>";
}

$result->free();
$db->close();


?>
</body></html>
```

It outputs this:

```
Book-O-Rama Search Results

query($query); $num_results = $result->num_rows; echo "
Number of books found: ".$num_results."

"; for($i=0; $i < $num_results; $i++) { $row = $result->fetch_assoc(); echo "
".($i+1).". Title: "; echo htmlspecialchars(stripslashes($row['title'])); echo"
Author: "; echo stripslashes($row['author']); echo "
ISBN: "; echo stripslashes($row['isbn']); echo "
Price: "; echo stripslashes($row['price']); echo "

"; } $result->free(); $db->close(); ?>
```

I can't understand why and also the `echo $searchterm;` at the start isn't executed at all. 
P.s. I'm running the script with Xampp localhost.

Comment: Unfortunately there's a lot of cargo-cult programming in here. Testing for magic quotes and arbitrarily using `stripslashes` is not really something that's necessary. Using `addslashes` is the incorrect way of [properly escaping values](http://bobby-tables.com/php). When using `mysqli` you should be using parameterized queries and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation to accomplish this because you will create severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Comment: Have you tried replacing the `" "` marks with single backticks i.e. `echo "<p>Number of books found: ".$num_results."</p>";` becomes `echo '<p>' . 'Number of books found:' . $num_results . '</p>'; `

Comment: @tadman I'm just following this book since I'm new to PhP. This code is shown in the book in order to teach how to use a database with PhP, something for beginners. Topics about SQL injection come later.

Comment: That book is dangerously obsolete and will do more harm than good. When writing queries by hand, injection concerns are paramount. Even a single mistake left un-checked can destroy your site. I'd strongly recommend learning a more modern approach by picking a friendly 
[development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) that fits your needs and use the interfaces provided by that rather than tediously write everything from the ground up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is with your SQL query. Which, I might add, has left me nearly in tears.

```
" like '%".$searchterm."%"
```

You have a single quote opening at the first % without closing it after the trailing %. This is turning the rest of your code into a string.

Beyond this, I really recommend you read [This post on sanitizing input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3126072/what-are-the-best-php-input-sanitizing-functions/3126175#3126175?newreg=0b6c4fcd171a465fbee9d3bc504764e7). Your code is ridiculously vulnerable, especially dropping sanitized variables directly into your query. You should be using [PDO bound variables](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php) for any variable being used in your SQL query. For output, you should be running them through [htmlspecialchars()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) (And probably strip_tags).

I recommend you pick up an up to date book on PHP/MYSQL. Your code reminds me of a Sams teach yourself PHP in 24 hours I bought in 2003 - no thought for security and purely about functionality.

Comment: There's no need to scrub HTML on insertion into the database. `htmlspecialchars` is meant to be used when displaying database content, not inserting.

Comment: Fair point; Updated. Meant to split the post up but got sidetracked and confused.