# Php + sql statement always returns successfull?

Tags: php, mysql, variables, echo

This is the code

```
<?php
include("global.php");

$username = mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes($_POST["strUserName"]));
$password = md5(mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes($_POST["strPassword"])));
$charid = mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes($_POST["charid"]));
$quest = mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes($_POST["strQuest"]));


$query = "SELECT * FROM wherei_users, wherei_characters WHERE wherei_users.username = '{$username}' AND wherei_users.password = '{$password}' AND wherei_characters.username =     '{$username}' AND wherei_characters.Id = '{$charid}'";
$result = mysql_query($query);
$yesorno = (mysql_num_rows($result) == 0) ? 'NO' : 'YES';


 if(empty($username) || empty($password) || empty($charid) || empty($quest) || $yesorno == "NO") {
$status="error";
$msg="InvalidData";
$actiontype="&actiontype=savequestdata";
$out=("$actiontype&status=$status&msg=$msg");
}

if ($yesorno = "YES") {
mysql_query("UPDATE wherei_characters SET strQuest = '{$quest}' WHERE username = '{$username}' AND id = '{$charid}'") or die(mysql_error());
$actiontype="&actiontype=savequestdata";
$status="success";
$out=("$actiontype&$status");
}

echo("$out");
?>
```

However, it always returns that the staus was success? When I go to my browser and just type the url, it returns this

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1
```

And when I set the values wrong on purpose it returns that the status is succesfull, you see that if ether `$username,$password,$charid,$quest`is empty or that `$yesorno` is `NO` then it should echo `&actiontype=savequestdata&status=error&msg=InvalidData`. No matter what I set the variables to, it returns `actiontype=savequestdata&sucess?

Answer (score 2):

This is your issue:

```
if ($yesorno = "YES") {
```

Spot it yet? .... ?

A single `=` in PHP is an **assignment operator**, so you are assigning the variable `$yesorno` to equal `"YES"`, which in PHP (not all languages) will also run the IF and will equate to TRUE.

You need either:
`==` the **comparison operator**
or
`===` the ***identical* comparison operator**.

---

---

Some unrelated, yet *important*, side notes on your code:

**Depreciated Function**
The `mysql_` function is depreciated. You should consider looking into/learning/using  [Mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).

More info: [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

**Validate and Sanitise**
I see you use `mysql_real_escape_string` on the `$_POST` variables.
Make sure you are checking the variables before you pass the data onto the database stage.
The user could enter anything into the form, and as you are using `mysql_` which is prone to injection attacks, you should be very careful.

[What are the best PHP input sanitizing functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3126072/what-are-the-best-php-input-sanitizing-functions/3126175#3126175)

**MD5**
Even php.net, the developers OF PHP, state:

> Note: Secure password hashing
>   It is not recommended to use this
>   function to secure passwords, due to the fast nature of this hashing
>   algorithm.

See here for why:
http://php.net/manual/en/faq.passwords.php#faq.passwords.fasthash