# Why insert query does not work?

Tags: php, mysql

my code returns success, but it does not insert the record to the table "bekuldottkerdesek". What is causing the problem?

Even select command fails, when I start to echo some records from the table.

This is how the table looks: [imgur](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SD4hZ.png)

```
    <?php
$servername = "***";
$username = "***";
$password = "***";
$dbname = "***";

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Bucharest');
$current_date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$check="SELECT * FROM bekuldottkerdesek WHERE kerdes = '$_POST[kerdes]'";
$res = mysqli_query($conn,$check);
if($res->num_rows){
   header("Location: /bekuld.php?hiba=1");
}
  else
  {
    $var1 = isset($_POST['at']) ? 1 : 0;
    $var2 = isset($_POST['bt']) ? 1 : 0;
    $var3 = isset($_POST['ct']) ? 1 : 0;
    $sql = "INSERT INTO bekuldottkerdesek (datum, kerdes, a, b, c, at, bt, ct)
    VALUES ('$current_date', '$_POST[kerdes]', '$_POST[a]', '$_POST[b]', '$_POST[c]', $at, $bt, $ct)";

    if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
        echo "New record created successfully";
    } else {
        echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
    }
    header("Location: /bekuld.php?hiba=2");
  }
$conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: All open to SQL injections.

Comment: Thank you for letting me know, I will search for sql incjection defending tutorials, now the #1 standpoint is to get my page working.

Comment: Actually by using prepared statements, you could do both in one step.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change the insert statment to ,error passing data from $_POST

```
 $sql = "INSERT INTO bekuldottkerdesek (datum, kerdes, a, b, c, at, bt, ct)
    VALUES ('$current_date', '{$_POST['kerdes']}', '{$_POST['a']}', '{$_POST['b']}', '{$_POST['c']}', $at, $bt, $ct)";
```

and change this statment

```
$check="SELECT * FROM bekuldottkerdesek WHERE kerdes = '$_POST[kerdes]'";
```

to

```
$check="SELECT * FROM bekuldottkerdesek WHERE kerdes = '{$_POST['kerdes']}'";
```

Comment: Please please please don't run queries that include non-validated / non-sanitised user input. Read this answer and make security a priority: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3126175/50151