# How to prevent XSS attack (php/pdo)

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, xss, sql-injection

I have functions, first:
JS:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {

        //dodavanje novog racuna
       $(function() { 
        $('#addFieldForm').submit(function(e) { 
            e.preventDefault();

            if ( $(this).parsley('validate') ) {

            $.ajax({
                url: "insertRacun.php",
                type: "POST",
                async: true, 
                data: { sifra:sifra,brojracuna:$("#brojracuna").val(),sufiks:$("#sufiks").val(),kupac:$("#kupac").val(),adresa:$("#adresa").val(),grad:$("#grad").val(),pib:$("#pib").val(),total:$("#total").text(),valuta:$("#valuta").val(),nacin:$("#nacin").val(),datum:$("#datum").val(),rok:$("#rok").val(),isporuka:$("#isporuka").val(),napomena:$("#napomena").val(),interna:$("#interna").val(),ponovi:$("#ponovi").val()},           
                dataType: "html",
etc...
```

php:

```
try {        
                $STH = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO racuni (br, sufiks, kupac, adresa, grad, pib, total,valuta,nacin,datum,rok,isporuka,napomene,interne, user_id,sifra) VALUES (:0,:1,:2,:3,:4,:5,:6,:7,:8,:9,:10,:11,:12,:13,:14,:15)");
                $STH->bindParam(':0', $_POST['brojracuna']);
                $sufiks=$_POST['sufiks'];
                $STH->bindParam(':1', $sufiks);
        $STH->bindParam(':2', $_POST['kupac']);
                $STH->bindParam(':3', $_POST['adresa']);
etc....
```

and when I try to add:

```
Luciansdasadsda"><script>alert(1)</script>
```

then I get in database the same value.

So How I can prevent XSS and SQL injection in my code?
ALso how to prevent Denial of service (causing excessive amounts of rows to be created)?

Comment: There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.I would suggest that you find a development forum (perhaps [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/)?) to work out generalities. Then, when you have specific coding issues, come back to StackOverflow and we'll be glad to help.

Comment: A couple of useful SO questions: [What's the best method for sanitizing user input with PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/129677/whats-the-best-method-for-sanitizing-user-input-with-php). Also: [What are the best PHP input sanitizing functions?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3126072/what-are-the-best-php-input-sanitizing-functions). Although has been mentioned - it is really about `output` where the concern lies. imo,  Looking after both input data and what you send out is the most reliable way to proceed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[**OWASP Cross Site Scripting (XSS) Prevention Cheat Sheet**
https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_%28Cross_Site_Scripting%29_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_%28Cross_Site_Scripting%29_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet)

---

The string value you're passing in to the database is being stored in the database. That's the expected behavior. Nothing in the MySQL, PDO, or prepared statements with bind placeholders is designed to prevent a string that looks like javascript from being stored.

That's all designed to prevent malicious strings from being interpreted as part of a SQL statement, ala **XKCD Exploits of a Mom** https://xkcd.com/327/

```
  Robert'; DROP TABLE students; --
```

So, you're handling "Little Bobby Tables" just fine.

You're asking about handling Bobby's cousin: "Shifty Earl".

```
  <script>alert('hello')</script>
```

We can get Shifty Earl's name inserted into the table just fine; there's no malicious SQL Injection to be thwarted.

The problem comes when we go to put "Shifty Earl"'s name back out on a web page.

We have to treat his name as being *potentially unsafe* (just like we did with Little Bobby Tables).

Here, it's unsafe to put it on a web page, unless we properly escape it.

So, how do we escape that to make it safe for display?

PHP has a nifty function called **`htmlentities`**. (Other languages/libraries have equivalent functions.)

The return from:

```
 htmlentities("<script>alert('hello')</script>")
```

will be something like this:

```
 &lt;script&gt;alert('hello')&lt;/script&gt;
```

Note that "**`&lt;`**" is called an html entity. It represents a "less than" character, but it will *not* be interpreted as the beginning of a tag. We'd get an equivalent result with "**`&#60;`**".

When we put that escaped/encoded string out on a web page, what the browser displays looks like the original string...

```
 <script>alert('hello')</script>
```

But, this is *not* and will *not* be interpreted as HTML tags.

**How do you prevent XSS vulnerabilities?**

By properly escaping all potentially unsafe values (by replacing HTML tag characters with an equivalent html entity) when those values are incorporated into a web page (at the time the web page is being prepared to be sent to the client.)

The database really has nothing to do with it.

The reason we don't do the "htmlentities" escaping when we store string in the database is that it's not the right place to do it.

Someone looking at your code is going to see that a potentially unsafe value is being put onto the web page, and will add the appropriate `htmlentities` function there, either right before it's put to the page. And then we'd get double escaping, encoding the values a second time.

The right place to do the escaping is *right when* the value is put on the web page.

There are other sources of potentially unsafe values, values read in from a file, from some other table, or values supplied by the user on a web form. It would wonky for the code to assume that values from one particular column in one particular table is "safe", and that values from other sources aren't safe.

---

[**OWASP SQL Injection**
https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection)

[**OWASP Cross Site Scripting (XSS) Prevention Cheat Sheet**
https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_%28Cross_Site_Scripting%29_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_%28Cross_Site_Scripting%29_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet)

Comment: Old answer but i wil comment annyway... `htmlentities()` has three params they are all important to stop (most) XSS.. Especially the encoding param because "If omitted, the default value of the encoding varies depending on the PHP version in use. In PHP 5.6 and later, the default_charset configuration option is used as the default value. PHP 5.4 and 5.5 will use UTF-8 as the default. Earlier versions of PHP use ISO-8859-1" Using the wrong encoding on a encoded string can cause trouble and maybe bypasses.