# Is this contact form fully function?

Tags: php, html, phpmailer, contact-form

When filling out the form it is saying sent successfully. So I need to enable or include phpmailer? The form is being sent via submit.php but the contact form is an html page. Do I also need to make the contact page php as well. Chmod permissions for submit.php is 755. In the script I do have the email address properly. I have phpmailer installed, do I need to activate it?

```
<?php
// specify your email here

$to = 'example@example.com';

// Assigning data from $_POST array to variables
if (isset($_POST['name'])) { $name = $_POST['name']; }
if (isset($_POST['email'])) { $from = $_POST['email']; }
if (isset($_POST['company'])) { $company = $_POST['company']; }
if (isset($_POST['message'])) { $message = $_POST['message']; }

// Construct subject of the email
$subject = 'Contact Inquery ' . $name;

// Construct email body
$body_message .= 'NAME: ' . $name . "\r\n\n";
$body_message .= 'EMAIL: ' . $from . "\r\n\n";
$body_message .= 'SUBJECT: ' . $company . "\r\n\n";
$body_message .= 'MESSAGE: ' . $message . "\r\n\n";

// Construct headers of the message
$headers = 'From: ' . $from . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Reply-To: ' . $from . "\r\n";

$mail_sent = mail($to, $subject, $body_message, $headers);

if ($mail_sent == true) { ?>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        window.alert("Sent Successfuly.");
    </script>
<?php } else { ?>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        window.alert("Error! Please Try Again Later.");
    </script>
<?php
} // End else  
?>
```

Comment: You are currently not using PHPMailer at all; you are calling the PHP `mail()` function directly (and incorrectly). You need to at least *try* to read some docs. [This might be a better starting place](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/contactform.phps).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Currently, your form doesn't needs to be rendered by PHP. So, it cans be kept in an HTML file.
2. When you say:

   > The form is being sent via `submit.php`

   I think you want to say:

   > The form is being sent **to** `submit.php`

   If this is the case, then I think the source code you posted is the
   content of this file.
3. Concerning the email sending, you use the built-in PHP [mail()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) 
   function. But this function [use the sendmail binary](http://php.net/manual/en/mail.requirements.php) which needs to be
   installed on your server. Moreover, you have to [setup the appropriate
   settings](http://php.net/manual/en/mail.configuration.php) in the `php.ini` file in order to make your host correctly
   send the email.
4. PHPMailer is a good replacement as it doesn't require any external
   dependencies. This [simple example](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer#a-simple-example) will show you basically how to use
   it.

**N.B:** I see that you PHP code is very simple and I deduce that you're a beginner, that you took this source code somewhere and that you don't really understand it. That's right. You have to start from somewhere.

**BUT:**

Be careful with this code! It takes the user inputs and sends it
**without any sanity checks**. I recommend you **to not deploy this code in production environment** (if it's for testing and learning, that's right).

Look at [this answer about PHP user input sanitation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3126175/427157). It doesn't talk about sanitation for email sending. But it might be a good starting point to understand how it works basically. Then you have to search by yourself.