# Remove <script> tags AND variant like &lt;script&gt;

Tags: javascript, php, sanitization

I need to sanitize (in php) a string containing html by removing javascript code in it (if there is) and keep the rest of the html.

I'm aware of strip_tags(); or some preg_replace. But all of them only cover the removing of the tag "script". But "script>" can be writted differently, i could write it like in the title of this post or with other variation of encoding.

How can i be sure to safely remove any javascript?

Comment: I think there are methods like html_escape_string or mysqli.prepare ... I think you should http://google.it?first

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are the best PHP input sanitizing functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3126072/what-are-the-best-php-input-sanitizing-functions)

Comment: There's also [encodeURI()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_encodeuri.asp), it doesn't use the html character codes like the other comments but it's another way...