# how to secure pasword field in php

Tags: security, xss, sql-injection, php-5.6

I have 2 fields(text box in **html form**) user_name and password.

*example=* 
`<?php

$mail = $_POST['mail'];

$pswrd = $_POST['passwrd']; 
$addtouser = $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO`user_table`(`emails`,`passwordss`) VALUES ('$mail', '$pswrd')"); 
 ?>`

How to **secure Password field** from **SQL Injection** and **XSS** (Cross Site Scripting) in php 5.6 and mysql on **INSERT and select query** ?
is password field accept all special characters like as " , ' ,  > etc ?
‌i am new in php,
‌i need full example code and security tips that prevent password field from sql injection and xss.
 sorry for bad typing. i am new in stackoverflow.
Thanks in advance !!!

Comment: there's a lot to this question really. Hash the password before storing it, re-hash login attempts to compare against the db version. Use https. limit login attempts to prevent brute force... the list goes on.

Comment: you're going to get down votes and close votes with your question in it's current state. I suggest editing your question to make it clear what you've tried and what your direct issue is.

Answer (score -1):

Prepared statements are one of the best ways to prevent SQL injections. i.e..xss,

using **PDO**, have a look at this page

[php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php)

**PHP's input filters**

[https://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/01/keeping-web-users-safe-by-sanitizing-input-data/](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/01/11/keeping-web-users-safe-by-sanitizing-input-data/)

**sanitization functions**

http://php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.php

**similimar question:**

[What's the best method for sanitizing user input with PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/129677/whats-the-best-method-for-sanitizing-user-input-with-php)

[What are the best PHP input sanitizing functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3126072/what-are-the-best-php-input-sanitizing-functions)
[How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php/60496#60496)

Comment: Thank you @Tegito123 . Is password field accept all special characters like as " , ' , > etc ?
`select emails, passwordss from user_table`

Comment: SQLi != XSS. 2 different injection attacks.