# Database connectivity using JSON

Tags: php, sql, json, sql-server

my php code,

```
<?php
 header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");
 $obj = json_decode($_GET["x"], false);
 $serverName = "AE58RETY245YU"; 
 $connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"Test", "UID"=>"bala", 
 "PWD"=>"bala");
 $conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);
 if( $conn ) {
 echo "Connection established.<br />";
 }else{
 echo "Connection could not be established.<br />";
 die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
 }
 $outp=array();
 $sql = "SELECT Point FROM ".$obj->table."LIMIT".$obj->limit;
 $stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql );
 while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) ) {
 $outp=$row['Point'];
 }
 echo json_encode($outp);
?>
```

my html code,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<h2>Get data as JSON from a PHP file on the server.</h2>
<p>The JSON received from the PHP file:</p>
<p id="demo"></p>
<script>
var obj, dbParam, xmlhttp;
obj = { "table":"PointEvent", "limit":10 }; 
dbParam = JSON.stringify(obj);
xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = this.responseText;
}
};
 xmlhttp.open("GET", "testsql.php?x=" + dbParam, true);
 xmlhttp.send();

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Hi ,

Above is my PHP and HTML code,i try to connect sql database using Json(Encode and Decode method) and try to print single column but the error am getting was

> 'Warning: sqlsrv_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in'.

Can anyone please help me with this things.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

I found concatenation issue in your query "add space" otherwise query looks something like "SELECT Point FROM **mytableLIMIT1**"

From

```
$sql = "SELECT Point FROM ".$obj->table."LIMIT".$obj->limit;
```

to

```
$sql = "SELECT Point FROM ".$obj->table." LIMIT ".$obj->limit;
```

Also handle exception properly by adding the line before while

```
if( $stmt === false ) { /*!Handle exception here*/ }
```

It seems you are new to programming. Never trust the raw user input like $_GET["x"] on working with database. Do proper sanitization, otherwise would end up in sql injection.

Go thru the following links to learn more

[What are the best PHP input sanitizing functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3126072/what-are-the-best-php-input-sanitizing-functions)

[How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: i use space in query, but i didn't get exact output. My output is like Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 42000 [SQLSTATE] => 42000 [1] => 102 [code] => 102 [2] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near '10'. [message] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near '10'. ) )

Comment: I think it might be the issue of escaping content. Did you used something $ in the query variable content, might be the table name?

Comment: sry i didn't get u. can u please write the query here,how to use the  $ in the query variable content, might be the table name....pleaseeee

Comment: Is the variable $obj->table having string "$" in it? Eg. "mydatabase$mytablename"

Comment: Eg. $a = "stack"; $b = " overflow"; echo "$a$b";//stack overflow. echo "$a\$b";//stack$b

Answer (score 0):

Row with `$stmt = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql);` statement can cause your problem. I think that `$sql` is not formed well. I'm not sure that MS SQL Server has `'LIMIT'` keyword, so try with this first: `$sql = "SELECT Point FROM ".$obj->table;` .

You also must always check `sqlsrv_query()` result, before using `sqlsrv_fetch_array()`:

```
$sql = "SELECT Point FROM ".$obj->table;
$stmt = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql);
if( $stmt === false ) {
    echo "Error (sqlsrv_query): ".print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true);
    exit;
}
...
```