# How to save PHP HTTP_USER_AGENT to MySQL field

Tags: php, mysql, environment-variables

I have a simple feedback form PHP script that I would like to enhance by adding the $_SERVER[HTTP_USER_AGENT] data to the row in the database that I'm saving.

I keep getting parse errors when I try a simple insert, passing '$_SERVER[HTTP_USER_AGENT]' as a typical string. Should I bundle it in some way, so that the characters used in that Server variable are not triggering such errors?

(The INSERT query runs fine without that field, btw.)

Thanks.

Comment: Without both erraneous code and exact error messages your question is quite senseless. Please learn to provide such an information in the future questions

Answer (score 9, accepted):

My bet is that there is a `'` in the user agent strings that are causing the parser error.

The User-Agent string returned to PHP is under control of the local browser, which means that you need to treat it no differently from regular user input. A malicious user or a user who has been infected by a virus/trojan/worm could change the user agent string to cause an SQL injection attack. At the very least, you need to escape it (with [mysql_real_escape_string()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) for example. My bet is that once you do this, your parser errors should also go away. Better yet, try to move to using [prepared statements](http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/4.1/prepared-statements.html) if your system allows this.

Comment: Thanks for explaining the solution and its reasoning.

Comment: @Andrew Perfect to inform him about security mistake .
Thank you to share your knowledge

Answer (score 1):

Does

```
mysql_query("
INSERT INTO
    db_table
VALUES (
    ...
    '" . mysql_real_escape_string($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']) . "'
    ...
)");
```

not work? Can you show us your whole query? What are the exact error-messages?

Comment: What do you mean by "single operator"? If you mean that, I don't specify the fields and only use the `VALUES`-Operator: the answer is "no"

Answer (score 0):

Without an actual error message it's hard to say what particular problem you encounter with.
But to solve all possible issues,

- First of all, you **must** read an official manual page to make yourself understand PHP strings syntax: http://php.net/types.string
- Then, you have to understand Mysql proper syntax. I've explained it already [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2993027/in-php-when-submitting-strings-to-the-db-should-i-take-care-of-illegal-characters/2995163#2995163)
- Finally, you have to put everything together

like this:

```
$agent = mysql_real_escape_string($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
$sql   = "INSERT INTO `table` set useragent = '$agent'";
$res   = mysql_query($sql) or trigger_error(mysql_query.$sql);
```

Running your queries this way you'll never have any problem. Or comprehensive error message at least.