# sql injection / Browser-Hijacker prevention php

Tags: php, security, sql-injection

I have a website where I can't use html_entities() or html_specialchars() to process user input data. Instead, I added a custom function, which in the end is a function, which uses an array $forbidden to clean the input string of all unwanted characters. At the moment I have '<', '>', "'" as unwanted characters because of sql-injection/browser hijacking. My site is encoded in utf-8 - do I have to add more characters to that array, i.e. the characters '<', encoded in other charsets?

Thanks for any help,

Maenny

Comment: Why can't you use htmlentities()?

Comment: because it does weird things with kyrillic characters, which I want to be enabled for user input.

Comment: have you tried using htmlentities() with the optional charset argument?

Comment: You can't use htmlspecialchars with utf8 encoding? See the docs for encoding types: http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php

Comment: well, yes I can use utf-8 with htmlentities, but when I do, in my DB, a word like Начало will show up as &#1071;&#1074;&#1083;&#1077;&#1085;&#1080;&#1077; &#1072;&#1073;&#1089;&#1086;&#1083;&#1102;&#1090;&#1085;&#1086;&#1075;&#1086; &#1079;&#1083;&#1072;,
which is kind of hard to read... So what i need is a possibility to have Начало saved in the way it is, and, at the same time, have no security issue...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. htmlentities nor htmlspecialchars functions has nothing to do with sql injection
2. to prevent injection, you have to follow some rules, I've described them all **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2993027/in-php-when-submitting-strings-to-the-db-should-i-take-care-of-illegal-characters/2995163#2995163)**
3. to filter HTML you may use htmlspecialchars() function, it will harm none of your cyrillic characters

Comment: its true that htmlentities or htmlspecialchars have nothing to do with sql injection, that would be for browser-hijacking. 
Nevertheless, it seems like the problem I have really is a encoding problem, because all of the cyrillic characters are sent through POST and hereby converted to ampersand. I haven't found a way to convert ampersand to utf-8 characters, anyone has an idea for that?
Maenny

Comment: @Maenny html_entity_decode() is idea for that, but instead of constant decoding you have to do it only once and then stop encoding at all.

Answer (score 0):

You should escape `"`, too. It is much more harm than `'`, because you often enclose HTML attributes in `"`. But, why don't you simlpy use `htmlspecialchars` to do that job?

Futhermore: It isn't good to use one escaping function for both SQL and HTML. HTML needs escaping of tags, whereas SQL does not. So it would be best, if you used `htmlspecialchars` for HTML output and `PDO::quote` (or `mysql_real_escape_string` or whatever you are using) for SQL queries.

But I know (from my own experience) that escaping all user input in SQL queries may be really annoying and sometimes I simply don't escape parts, because I think they are "secure". But I am sure I'm not always right, about assuming that. So, in the end I wanted to ensure that I really escape *all* variables used in an SQL query and therefore have written a little class to do this easily: http://github.com/nikic/DB Maybe you want to use something similar, too.

Answer (score -1):

Put this code into your header page. It can prevent SQL injection attack in PHP.

function clean_header($string)
{
$string = trim($string);

// From RFC 822: “The field-body may be composed of any ASCII
// characters, except CR or LF.”
if (strpos($string, “\n“) !== false) {
$string = substr($string, 0, strpos($string, “\n“));
}
if (strpos($string, “\r“) !== false) {
$string = substr($string, 0, strpos($string, “\r“));
}

return $string;
}

Comment: whis disaster should be stopped somehow