# Insert All Post Data into MySQL Database

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, mysqli, prepared-statement

The following topic is close to what I'm trying to ask, but it's outdated considering the mysql functions are deprecated in php now and there are prepared statements for preventing sql injection. [insert all $_POST data into mysql using PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3338138/insert-all-post-data-into-mysql-using-php)

Basically, I have a huge number of columns in my database that all need to get filled up when I submit this form.  The form matches each column with an input field of the same name (the name attribute on the input field is the same as the column name it belongs in. So `$_POST['firstName']` goes in the `firstName` column, and so on).

Is there a way using mysqli or PDO that I could easily just take all my POST data and automatically insert it into the MySQL table without going through each field by hand?  I could code them all out using prepared statements, but there are a ton of columns and I'd like to get them done all at once if possible.

This is the beginning of the long version I don't really want to have to complete.

```
$stmt = $connection->prepare("INSERT INTO area_retreat 
(user,firstName,lastName,...etc) 
VALUES 
(?,?,?,...etc)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
user=VALUES(user),
firstName=VALUES(firstName),
lastName=VALUES(lastName),
...etc
");
$stmt->bind_param("sss",
    $username,
    $_POST['firstName'],
    $_POST['lastName']
 );

$stmt->execute();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To avoid errors you definitely need to store the list of variables one way or another. It could be as simple as an array:

```
$fields = array('firstName', etc.);
```

Then you can loop through your array to generate your sql statement dynamically and using named placeholders instead of question marks, you only need to bind them once. You can also store the values in an array and send that array as a parameter to `execute()`:

```
// start of query
$values = array();
$query = '...';
foreach ($fields as $field)
{
  if (isset($_POST[$field]))
  {
    // add to query
    $query .= "...";
    // add value to array so that you can feed the array to `execute`
    $values[':' . $field] = $_POST[$field];
  }
}
// add end of query
$query .= '...';

$stmt->execute($values);
```

If you want to use the same variables in an `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` section, you can do another loop or build an insert section that you can use twice after looping once.

Comment: That actually is more what I was looking for than what I though I was looking for.  And I suppose I could query the table and get the field names dynamically too, so instead of being coding all the field names into the `$fields` array by hand or being unsafe and pulling them from `$_POST` I'd get them from the table itself and fill the `$fields` array that way.

Answer (score 1):

`INSERT INTO area_retreat VALUES (?, ?, ...)` -- however, you have to match **ALL** columns as shown in the database.

If you have an auto increment ID, you will need to provide NULL for that column in the proper column order.