# Binding values to a JSON string using PHP

Tags: php, json

Using PHP, I'd like to bind a value to a JSON string similar to how it is done when preparing an SQL statement for a database using a question mark.  For example, I would like do something like the following:

```
$v1 = 'v1';
$k2 = 'k2';
$result = json_bind('[{"k1": ?}, {?: "v2"}]', $v1, $k2);
echo $result; // [{"k1": "v1"}, {"k2": "v2"}]
```

1. I don't want to just do a pure string replace as this technique doesn't escape/quote the values properly and it can't format values like arrays and objects properly.
2. I don't want to just create an array (or an object) first, assign my params, and use `json_encode` because this gets messy since PHP's syntax differs from JSON's syntax and I need something more dynamic because I may not always know the structure of the JSON.

Is there already a library or function that can do this very thing?

Comment: What is `json_bind()`

Comment: That is a "made-up" function to demonstrate what I want to do.

Comment: preg_replace_callback

Comment: `preg_replace_callback` can't necessarily distinguish between a question mark in a literal and elsewhere.  Looking for something that takes a more lexical analyzer approach.

Comment: "I may not always know the structure of the JSON". Wow would like see how you test it and are you sure the result is always OK. I think the library not exist because it would be mega magic.

Comment: what works for me is to put everything in an associative array en then json_encode() it. Keys and values are separate, and the function takes care of correctly writting the json string.

Comment: You would have to write your own lexer then, if you can't ensure there's no literal `?` in your template. It seems there would be little use for such a thing outside of trivial structures. Enumerated placeholders wouldn't make sense for deeply nested structures IMO. Though I would say a regex is [feasible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2583472/regex-to-validate-json); it's more tricky to use it for search and replace here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's sort of doable with a simple regex "tokenizer" - by skipping strings mostly.

```
#-- Replace `?` placeholders
function json_bind($template, ...$vars) {
    return preg_replace_callback(
        '/
            [{}[\],:] \K |             # meta chars
            (true|false|null) \K |     # literals
            [-+\d.e]+ \K |             # numbers
            "([^"\\\\]+|\\\\.)*" \K |  # strings
            ([?])        # placeholder (do not skip)
         /x',
         function ($m) use (& $vars) {
             if ($m[0] == "?") {
                 return json_encode(array_shift($vars));
             }
         },
         $template
    );
}
```

While that's not a very complete/clean regex, it should skip over most standard JSON structures and most strings (see [Regex to validate JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2583472/regex-to-validate-json) for better regexps). Which is how you can find literal `?` placeholders.

Notably that doesn't take care of semantically invalid templates, like array params for JSON keys e.g.

Comment: This is much better than what is mentioned here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8464335/question-mark-placeholder/8464422

Comment: Although a nifty solution, the OP didn't want to use json_encode

Comment: @C.vanDorsten OP didn't want to use json_encode *as part of* manual array construction. Didn't imply zero usage at all.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there already a library or function that can do this very thing?

No.

Comment: Surely with a Rep od 23k+ you realise this is not an answer

Comment: @RiggsFolly why not? It is the answer to the question. What should be a correct answer then? A completed implementation of what OP wants?

Comment: Its a comment, not an answer

Comment: @RiggsFolly I disagree. Comments are for clarifying the question or giving tips. The question is clear, the answer as well. It just happens to be a short one.

Comment: This answers the question thoroughly, although not very explainatory.

Answer (score 0):

How can you not know the JSON structure? What than is the use of passing values to a function in order to bind values to a string, if you can not distinguish a question mark being a key or a value?

In a sence you are saying I do know what I want to bind and I pass it in an arbitrary way to a function, although I have no clue as to the structure of the source JSON string. Thus I have no clue as to the outcome being correct or not.

Why would anyone want to have such a thing?

You simply have to go with the answer of @Bart Friederichs. This is the only proper answer to your question.

Comment: It seems people are getting hung up on the fact that I said that "I may not always know the structure of the JSON".  So let me clarify....I may have two or three JSON templates in a closed environment.  Each has a similar structure, but are slightly different.  For example, `{"order": {"customer": {"id": ?}}}` and `{"customer": {"id": ?}}`.  I would like to create a simple method that has two parameters: `addCustomerId($json, $id)`.

Comment: If that is the actual layout, just stick with a global search  on " : ?" and  replace it with (": ".$id) (roughtly speaking that is) and you have what you want, although you at first said you don't want to.