# URL and mod_rewrite: use many special chars and keep data safe from attacks

Tags: php, mysql, security, mod-rewrite, pdo

I'm working on a site where contents pages are handled with `mod_rewrite` and I'm trying to make the URL managed with `mod_rewrite` protected from `SQL injections` with some char restriction, because users can create pages contents like this:

```
http://site.com/content-type/Page-created-by-user
```

My doubts come when they insert something like:

```
http://site.com/architect/Giovanni+Dall'Agata
```

I need to insert `'` char because I can have names like this for example of famous architects, but I don't know if I can keep data safe and how prevent `SQL injections` with this character.

Should I do something particular to prevent attacks?

I'm using `PDO class` in `PHP` like this:

```
$architect = strip_tags (trim ($_REQUEST["architect"]));

// pdo class etc..
$pdo_stmt->bindParam (":arch", $architect, PDO::PARAM_STR);
// and the other code here...
```

Users can't create pages with these chars: `< > / \ * ? =` should I ban `'` and `"` too?
Or should I permit only one of `'` and `"` chars or can I use them together and keep server safe?

Comment: From a design perspective, you really want to be guarding against SQL injection as close to the database as possible instead of relying on other layers of your application--like your mod_rewrite rules--to provide that protection.  Your use of bound parameters in PDO is highly recommended in this regard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[$stmt->bindParam](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php) (and bindValue, and in general, prepared statements) are safe against SQL injection. All serious SB frameworks support a way of adding parameters to a query, and values added that way are sanitized. You should always do that and never insert <strike>variables</strike> data coming from users *(see comments)* manually into an SQL query string.

That still leaves the question of XSS injections, which are easier to miss (though also less dangerous); to avoid them, make sure you always use `htmlspecialchars($var,ENT_QUOTES)` (or urlencode, depending on the context).

Comment: However, sometimes we have to add a variable or two into query directly anyway. It's better to be armed for such a case instead of just forbidding it.

Comment: I would avoid it as a rule, unless it is a constant or otherwise obviously uncompromisable by the user. It is not enough for the code to be secure; it should *look* secure. Makes the probability of accidental slip-ups much smaller.

Comment: so, you'd better add it to the answer or at least mention that you are talking of data only. Because prepared statements can protect only data and can't help with any other part of query.

Comment: I was not too clear probably. It's not matter of terms used. It's rather of understanding. See what I mean, examples at the bottom: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2993027/in-php-when-submitting-strings-to-the-db-should-i-take-care-of-illegal-characters/2995163#2995163

Answer (score 0):

PDO automatically escapes characters like `'` so you should be ok, just make sure you have `register_globals` and `magic_quotes` turned off and always use `bindParam` for your queries.

Also if your talking about creating dynamic URL's you shouldn't have the `'` character in them anyways. I always use:

```
$str = preg_replace("([^0-9a-zA-Z\-])", "", $str);
```

Which removes anything thats not 0-9, a-z or a dash from the string.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, should I still use strip_tags (trim ("...")) If I work with PDO class?

Comment: As a matter of fact, PDO doesn't escape nothing. At least not in compatible mode. It uses different mechanism