# 40' OR '1'='1 this is prone to sql injection?

Tags: php, sql, mysql, sql-injection

I have developed a simple application for study of sql injection where i search for rate < 40 and retrive all the names having rate less than 40 but when i pass search as **40' OR '1'='1**
so it retrieves all the records from database table 
I know how to solve this problem but i don't know **40' OR '1'='1** how this statement works when i pass **40' OR '1'='1** can any one briefly tell me what happens when i pass **40' OR '1'='1** in search box ??

hoping for quick and positive response ...

```
<?php
include("conn.php");

$get_rate = $_GET['rate'];

$query = "select * from `sqlinjection`.`products` WHERE `products`.`rate` < '".$get_rate."'";


$result=mysql_query($query);

if($result == false)
{
    die(mysql_error());

}

while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
{

echo "Name".$row['srno']."<br/>";
echo "Name".$row['name']."<br/>";
echo "Rate".$row['rate']."<br/>";
}

?>
```

Comment: You can format source code with the `010110` toolbar button. I've done it for you this time.

Comment: @Alvaro - I was going to edit that but I'm minus 50 off reputation :-(

Comment: @Alvaro yeh i always had problem while posting source code. where is the option for 010110 .. how to format source code ?

Comment: @mr_eclair: The image was changed recently, it now looks like this: `{}`

Comment: @Piskvor yeh thanks a lot .. now i got it how to format source code.. thank u all .. for sharing ur awesome knowledge.. and providing best solution for my doubt.

Comment: @Piskvor: oops, I hadn't noticed neither the new icon nor the `<pre>` and `<code>` tags. I'm used to just hit `Ctrl+K` <:-)

Comment: A complete guide on SQL injecton protection: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2993027/in-php-when-submitting-strings-to-the-db-should-i-take-care-of-illegal-characters/2995163#2995163

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is **exactly how SQL Injection works**

Imagine the query to the database.  Usually it would be something like this:

```
select *
from products
where productID = '[some parameter]'
```

but in your case since the parameter has come from the user, and that user entered 40' OR '1'='1 you're left with:

```
select *
from products
where productID = '40' OR '1'='1'
```

as 1 = 1 it will select everything

The best way to prevent this is to use a parametrised query. [Excellent article.](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/04/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death.html)

Comment: yes i'm learning .. how to secure web application from sql injection but how this query works i hv doubt in that

Comment: Because normally you will have this productID = '[some parameter]'.  If I replace '[some parameter]' with 40' OR '1'='1 I'm left with productID = '40' OR '1'='1'

Comment: `a parametrised query such as Stored Procedures` are you sure you do quite understand what did you say?

Comment: Sorry I meant use a parametrised query, forget the stored procedures bit.  I think I mind was jumping ahead of what I was typing.

Answer (score 3):

Think about it in terms of what the resulting SQL query will look like:

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE rate<'40' OR '1'='1';
```

`'1'` does indeed equal `'1'` so `rate<'40' OR '1'='1'` will always be true, and every record will be returned. Have you seen this before: http://xkcd.com/327/ ?

Answer (score 2):

Try modifying your script by adding some debug information:

```
$get_rate = $_GET['rate'];
$query = "select * from sqlinjection.products WHERE products.rate < '".$get_rate."'";
echo $query;
```

You should see that resulting SQL is:

```
select * from sqlinjection.products WHERE products.rate < '20' OR '1'='1'
                                                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

The quote inside the value of `$get_rate` terminates the string `'20'`, so the following `OR '1'='1'` is interpreted as SQL. Since `'1' = '1'` is always true, this query returns all rows.

Comment: @Marks +1 thats better.. to learn how it works by actually passing the sqlinjection cheat code .. through query..

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have an application that ultimately tries this:

```
SELECT somefield FROM sometable WHERE rate < '$yourRate'
```

which would normally (e.g. with `40` as the input) get expanded to

```
SELECT somefield FROM sometable WHERE rate < '40'
```

However, if you don't sanitize your SQL input, and a malicious user enters `40' OR '1'='1`, the query becomes

```
SELECT somefield FROM sometable WHERE rate < '40' OR '1'='1'
```

and since `'1'='1' is always true, it is equivalent to

```
SELECT somefield FROM sometable
```

Now, what to do? If the app is still small, I'd suggest switching to [mysqli](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/54239-introduction-to-mysqli-and-prepared-statements/) - it allows you to use Prepared Statements, which are much more resilient against this. If not, at the very least sanitize your parameters. That means, if there's supposed to be an integer as a parameter, cast the input to integer; if a string, use the language's escape function - in PHP, this would be [mysql_real_escape_string](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php). Example in PHP:

```
$get_count = $_GET['count']; // an example of integer
$get_rate = $_GET['rate'];   // an example of float
$comment = $_GET['comment']; // an example of string

$sanitized_count = (int) $get_count; // now we're *sure* it's an int, and nothing else
$sanitized_rate = (float) $get_rate; // ditto
$sql_sanitized_comment = mysql_real_escape_string($comment); // you need to have the mySQL connection open to use this function (for charset purposes)

$query = "select * from sqlinjection.products 
            WHERE 
              products.rate < ".$sanitized_rate."
              OR products.comment = '" . $sql_sanitized_comment . "'
            LIMIT " . $sanitized_count;
```

This way, the parameters are safe from SQL injection.

Answer (score 1):

Basically what happens is the statement

```
SELECT * FROM blah WHERE rate > 'param'
```

gets passed 40' OR '1'='1 which becomes

```
SELECT * FROM blah WHERE rate > '40' OR '1'='1
```

Since 1 = 1 for all rows all the rows are returned.