# ORDER BY $order - Possible security hole?

Tags: php, security, url

I have a code like this:

```
ORDER BY $order
```

Where '$order' is taken from the url like:

http://mywebsite.com/page.php?order=Bananas DESC

Could someone with wrong intentions add their own code at the end of the URL and thus do whatever they like?

Comment: Good question. Here you can find a whitelist example code http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2993027/in-php-when-submitting-strings-to-the-db-should-i-take-care-of-illegal-characters/2995163#2995163

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't check what's on `$order` variable, then your code is definitely exposed to potential SQL injection attacks.

So, you need to sanitize your input variables by making sure what you get from the `GET` command is actually a valid `order by` clause (you can use a regular expression for that).

Or you can do some kind of encoding for your application to form the order by clauses. Something like making:

```
http://mywebsite.com/page.php?orderField=1&orderType=DESC
```

And then mapping in your code `1` to `Bananas` for `orderField` parameter, and `ASC` or `DESC` for your `orderType` parameter.

Comment: The only check I'm doing is to see if the order field is empty to assign a default order. I don't have anything other than that.
How would I go about checking and preventing attacks? I have 9 possible 'order' that should be allowed.

Comment: @Michael - You therefore have a "whitelist" which is the proper way of validating input. Just check the variable at the end is on of your 9 allowed fields. Job done!

Comment: I'm going to give the whitelsit a go then. Cheers guys, I'm blown away by how quickly you get answers on here.

Answer (score 2):

Probably yes. Depending on your config the attacker could insert something like this:

"Bananas; drop table students"

Subqueries instead of multiple statements might be possible too

I'd either build the order clause myself, or compare it against a whitelist.

Comment: It is worth noting that vulnerability to query stacking (adding a second query on the end) does depend on the combination of DBMS and DB language library being used. Some combinations are inherently safe from this particular category of vector and some are not.

Answer (score 0):

Example :

```
SELECT * FROM bugs ORDER BY $column $direction
```

You must define possible options :

```
 $column =array('id','name',....);
$direction = array('ASC','DESC');
```

then :

```
if(array_key_exists ($_REQUEST['column'],$column){
    $column = $column[  $_REQUEST['column']  ];
}else{
...defaults....
}
```