# Is using mysqli_real_escape_string enough to secure my query string?

Tags: php, mysql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Are dynamic mysql queries with sql escaping just as secure as prepared statements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4771984/are-dynamic-mysql-queries-with-sql-escaping-just-as-secure-as-prepared-statements)

Is using only `mysqli_real_escape_string` enough to secure a query? Or is there more to consider when trying to securely query a database?

Comment: @irc I *was* working on it. Might as well use your answer now since it's just what I was going to say.

Comment: You could use prepared statements. Follow that link on ircmaxwell's comment.

Comment: Can you show an example of what you are doing?

Comment: @Null: If you expanded, I would have deleted my comment.  Just that if you had planned on leaving it like that (which I didn't know at the time), it was kind of pointless.  But I understand why you did it ;-)...

Comment: @irc I wouldn't leave it like that. I haven't used SO in a while... It seems like the dynamics of the site have changed a bit. I used to key in a short answer as fast as I could and even then chances are somebody would beat me to it.

Comment: Ok, I guess there are already a lot of topics about that function and securing query: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=mysqli_real_escape_string+secure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If used everywhere correctly real_escape_string is an option. But consider the following code:

```
$page = $_GET['page'];
$sql = 'SELECT `name` FROM `user` WHERE `id` = ' . mysqli_real_escape_string($page);
```

Safe or not? real_escape_**string** can only be used to escape strings inside quotation marks. `$page` could be `1 OR id IN (2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)` → no quotation marks, no real escaping. Casting to the correct datatype (int) might help in this case. You're better off using prepared statements, they are not as easily to mis-use.

Comment: Which is why you should never *escape* an integer.  You should always either cast, or enforce the type explicitly...

Comment: Do the `mysqli_real_escape_string()` function not normally need the connexion to database argument ?

Comment: @SébastienGarcia-Roméo: by default it will use the currently active connection (I think that's the one opened most recently)

Comment: What if I forcefully input all my data as quoted string no matter what the data type it should be, in that case ```id` = '1 OR id IN (2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)'`` condition will fail

Comment: @AunRizvi: I don't understand your comment. I think your mardown is off (code is not highlighted properly). Who inputs the data? Who's quoting the data? Which condition will fail?

Comment: @knittl consider the query in your given answer, if I keep the value of id in quotes, this will make the value as string and yet it will work fine with integers as string, but I will be safe from SQL Injections by using real_escape_string, can I use such practice to overcome the integers problem using this function?

Comment: @AunRizvi: automatic type conversion is a very dirty workaround. I don't like it. I don't know about the performance implications, and many other DBMSs won't allow that.