# Prepared statements in SIlkJS

Tags: javascript, mysql, prepared-statement, v8, silkjs

I am looking into using SilkJS (http://silkjs.org/) to build a web-application that utilizes MySQL. A requirement of this project is that it supports using prepared statements for MySQL. Does anyone know of a way to utilize prepared statements in SilkJS?

In response to those of you that might say to just "escape the input", that is not a secure way to use MySQL.

In response to those of you that might say to just use NodeJS, NodeJS is asynchronous and I am looking to use synchronous logic (SilkJS is synchronous). In response to those of you that might say to "just get used to asynchronous because it's so much better", no, no it is not.

Comment: SEE: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4771984/are-dynamic-mysql-queries-with-sql-escaping-just-as-secure-as-prepared-statement

(SilkJS does not currently provide prepared statements)