# Properly Escaping with MySQLI | query over prepared statements

Tags: php, mysqli

I have read this:

*will help you NOT against injection.
Beause escaping is just a string formatting facility, not injection preventer by any means.
Go figure.
However, escaping have something in common with prepared statements:
Them both doesn't guarantee you from injection if
you are using it only against notorious "user input", not as a strict rule for the building ANY query, despite of data source.
in case you need to insert not data but identifier or a keyword.*

On the following Post: [Are dynamic mysql queries with sql escaping just as secure as prepared statements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4771984/are-dynamic-mysql-queries-with-sql-escaping-just-as-secure-as-prepared-statement)

So my question is that using:

```
$Var = "UserInput Data Possible SQL Injection";
$mysqli->real_escape_string($Var);
```

does not provide protection against SQL Injection?

I want to use `$mysqli->query();` so I can use `fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);` Because to be frank, I have no idea how to fetch the results as an array after using a `prepared` statement.

So If I have this in my Database Connection:

```
$STD = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', 'xx', 'xx');
$STD->set_charset('utf8');

if ($STD->connect_error) {
    die("Standard Access Has Been Revoked. Please Contact Administration"); 
}elseif (!$STD){
die ("Other problem With Connecting To Database, Please Contact Administration");
}
```

as stated in the manual for `real_escape_string`

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php

The above lists:

*Caution
Security: the default character set
The character set must be set either at the server level, or with the API function mysqli_set_charset() for it to affect mysqli_real_escape_string(). See the concepts section on character sets for more information.*

Which links to: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.set-charset.php

---

My overall question can split into three options, the first would be asking for a `fetch_array()` equlivant for `prepared` statements, which will provide full SQL injection prevention due to prepared statements sending data as raw.

---

The **first question** in this format follows:

I'm using a Query as:

```
$GetCompletedQuery = $STD->query("SELECT Status FROM UserCompletion WHERE `UserID`=' ". $STD->real_escape_string($_SESSION['UID']) ."'");
$GetCompletedArray = $GetCompletedQuery->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
```

Which returns:

> Array ( [Status] => 1 )

But using prepared statements:

```
$GetCompletedQuery = $STD->prepare("SELECT Status FROM UserCompletion WHERE `UserID`=?");
$GetCompletedQuery->bind_param('i', $_SESSION['UID']);
$GetCompletedQuery->execute();

$GetCompletedArray = $GetCompletedQuery->fetch_row;

print_r($GetCompletedArray);
```

Which returns:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_row() on a non-object in /var/www/New/API/Constants.php on line 17

The same appears when I try `fetch_array()` which I know cannot be used with prepared statements.

So what would be the option for using prepared statements?

---

**Second Question**

If I use My Usual Query as:

```
$GetCompletedQuery = $STD->query("SELECT Status FROM UserCompletion WHERE `UserID`=' ". $STD->real_escape_string($_SESSION['UID']) ."'");
```

which enabled me to use `fetch_array();`  is data properly secured from SQL injection?

---

**Third Question:**

Should I be escaping/protecting from SQL injection for a `$_SESSION['UID'];` as this is assigned in the following manor:

```
$InnerJoinQuery = $STD->query("
        SELECT Users.ID, Users.Username, Users.Password, UserInformation.LastName, UserInformation.Firstname, UserInformation.DOB
        FROM Users
        INNER JOIN UserInformation
        ON Users.ID = UserInformation.UserID WHERE Users.Username = '".$_SESSION['real_name']."'");
        $InnerJoinArray = $InnerJoinQuery->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);

    $_SESSION['UID'] = $InnerJoinArray['ID'];
    $_SESSION['Password'] = $InnerJoinArray['Password'];
    $_SESSION['Firstname'] = $InnerJoinArray['Firstname'];
    $_SESSION['LastName'] = $InnerJoinArray['LastName'];
    $_SESSION['DOB'] = $InnerJoinArray['DOB'];
```

*This snippet explained:*

User Logs in with username & password, the file gets information from the database based on `$_SESSION['real_name'];`
and adds to the $_SESSION array with the results, adding each into a different key.

The question for this chunk is should I even be escaping/protecting from SQL injection when the `$_SESSION['UID'];` is assigned through the database based on `$_SESSION['real_name'];`

Thankyou for your time for reading over this massive chunk.

Comment: **question 1.** you can fetch an array from prepared statement. there are many examples on here. **question 2** no **question 3.** yes

Comment: As long as it's a valid `mysqli_result` object, `fetch_array` is available. So your **Q1** code may looks like `$result=$GetCompletedQuery->execute();$array=$result->fetch_array()`. [Document](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.get-result.php
2. Yes, but it is very bad practice:

   - it will help you in this case but **only** in this case and deceive with anything else
   - manual escaping is just silly, better let driver to do it for you
3. YES, because there is no such thing like SQL injection but **improper formatting** ONLY

> is that using `$mysqli->real_escape_string($Var);` does not provide protection against SQL Injection?

I didn't change my mind: **sure, it doesn't.**
It will do only if you enclose the resulting value in quotes (and set proper encoding using `mysqli_set_charset()` to be strict).

Look, SQL injection not something essential, existing on it's own, but it's rather mere a consequence. A consequence of improperly formatted query.
When creating a query, you have to properly format every part of it. Not because of whatever "injection" but for the sake of it. When you're going to insert a string into query, you HAVE to put it into quotes, or you will get a syntax error. When you're going to insert a string into query, you HAVE to escape these quotes were used to delimit this string, or you will get a syntax error. And so on. It is proper formatting that should be your concern, not scaring tales about injection. And **as long as you have every dynamic query part properly formatted according to it's type - no injection ever could be possible**

So, the source of variable or it's value should never be your concern. But only it's place in the query:

- strings have to be enclosed in quotes and have these quotes escaped.
- numbers have to be cast to it's type.
- identifiers have to be enclosed in backticks and have these backticks doubled

When it's going for the *static* part of the query, hardcoded in the script, we don't use such strict standards - say, we're not enclosing every identifier in backticks.
But when it's going for the *dynamical* part of the query, applying formatting rules should be strict rule, as we cannot know variable content for sure.

By the way, there is another way to format your strings and numbers - prepared statements. It is not as convenient as it should be, but because it is using placeholders to represent your data in the query, it it recommended to use over silly manual formatting.