# "Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$id" in php

Tags: php, function, session

I am getting `Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$id` in the lines `$uid = $data->id;` and `$uname = $data->username;` of the following function:

```
public function userlogin()
{
    $sql = 'select id, username from login_user where email="'.$this->email.'"and password="'.$this->password.'"';
    $result = mysqli_query($this->cn,$sql);
    $numrows = mysqli_num_rows($result);
    if($numrows == 1)
    {
        $data = mysqli_fetch_field($result);
        $uid = $data->id;
        $uname = $data->username;

        $_SESSION['login'] = 1;
        $_SESSION['uid'] = $uid;
        $_SESSION['uname'] = $uname;
        $_SESSION['login_msg'] = 'Login Successfully...';

    }

}
```

Comment: Why are you calling `mysqli_fetch_field` function ?

Comment: mysqli_fetch_field returns the field definition info and not the data.

Comment: You should be using `mysqli_fetch_object`, not `mysqli_fetch_field`.

Comment: Please learn about [SQL injection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/601300/what-is-sql-injection) and consider what your code will do if someone sets their password to ";drop database;"

Comment: `echo '<pre>'.print_r($data, true).'</pre>';` works miracles for tracking down array/object issues. `var_dump($data);` if formatting does not concern you.

Comment: @rrauenza Nothing, since `mysqli_query` will not execute multiple queries. Please stop quoting little Bobby Tables.

Comment: you may want to use mysqli_fetch_object instead to get your query result as object. please read the manual.

Comment: @Barmar Ok, it doesn't do multiple statements -- but one could still malform the SQL to do something the coder didn't intend: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14323078/mysql-injection-query

Comment: @rrauenza Yes, that's true. I'm not saying ignore SQL injection, I just hate that example that everyone quotes. It's makes a nice XKCD cartoon, but we should strive for truth here.

Comment: **Never store plain text passwords!** Please use PHP's [built-in functions](http://jayblanchard.net/proper_password_hashing_with_PHP.html) to handle password security. If you're using a PHP version less than 5.5 you can use the `password_hash()` [compatibility pack](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat). Make sure that you [don't escape passwords](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36628418/1011527) or use any other cleansing mechanism on them before hashing. Doing so *changes* the password and causes unnecessary additional coding.

Comment: @barmar Agreed.  It's the simplest most destructive example I could think of, and wasn't aware mysqli restricted to a single query.  I'll refrain from using that as my example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you are getting

> Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$id

is because [`mysqli_fetch_field`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-field.php) doesn't return an object with an `id` property. It is used to fetch meta information about the column. You can see the full list of properties on their [document page](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-field.php).

You probably want to be using [`mysqli_fetch_object`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-object.php)

```
public function userlogin()
{
    $sql = 'select id, username from login_user where email="'.$this->email.'"and password="'.$this->password.'"';
    $result = mysqli_query($this->cn,$sql);
    $numrows = mysqli_num_rows($result);
    if($numrows == 1)
    {

        /* fetch object array */
        while ($data = mysqli_fetch_object($result)) {
          $uid = $data->id;
          $uname = $data->username;
        }

        /* free result set */
        mysqli_free_result($result);

        $_SESSION['login'] = 1;
        $_SESSION['uid'] = $uid;
        $_SESSION['uname'] = $uname;
        $_SESSION['login_msg'] = 'Login Successfully...';

    }

}
```