# Do "mysqli_stmt::bind_param" uses from "mysqli::real_escape_string" implicitly?

Tags: mysqli

Do **mysqli_stmt::bind_param** uses from **mysqli::real_escape_string** implicitly? Or we must do it manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither `mysqli_stmt::bind_param` does `mysqli::real_escape_string` implicitly, nor you have to do it manually.

First, **escaping is not a synonym for safety.** While binding is.
So, it's incomparable matters.
Please refer to my earlier answer for the explanation: [Properly Escaping with MySQLI | query over prepared statements](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14313305/285587)

Next, bind_param doesn't use escaping anyway - it's different mechanism
Please refer to another my answer with full explanation: [How prepared statements can protect from SQL injection attacks?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8265319/285587)