# & can't be inserted in MYSQL through PHP

Tags: php

It sounds strange to me. I have a simple PHP script that inserts data into MYSQL table.
Upon receiving the content from the client via AJAX the data is stored in a variable:

```
$content=$_POST['content']; 
$sql="insert into contents values('$content')";
mysql_query($sql);
```

The problem is that if the content contains a '&' symbol,the sub-string before & is stored in MYSQL and the rest of the string is discarded. If I try directly in MYSQL then it stores complete string containg & symbol.why?

Comment: I think your problem is the sql injection vulnerability. How about you use prepared statements instead? Also - note `mysql_` is deprecated, prefer mysqli or PDO instead.

Comment: This is extremely unsafe! Use `mysqli` or `pdo` instead of `mysql_`.

Comment: i used $content=mysql_real_escape_string($content) also, but it was in vain @BenjaminGruenbaum

Comment: @rosemary that's still an extremely fragile solution. [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: i am using mysqli in some of my scripts.thank you for your solution @BenjaminGruenbaum

Comment: @rosemary this IS an answer below... hint hint...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First off if this site is live take it down lol. This is classic sql injection vulnerability.

You need to be using `mysqli` now instead of mysql.

The way you use this is the same but it has this REALLY cool feature called ['real escape string'](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php)

What it does is parameterize the data before you pass it into the database

```
$content = $_POST['content']; 
$connection = new mysqli('ipaddress','username','password','database');
$content = $connection->real_escape_string($content);
$sql="insert into contents values('$content')";
$connection->query($sql);
```

This is a much safer way of passing in data

Comment: Using `mysqli` is not what makes it safe. I use `mysql` and obstinately refuse to use anything else, because I know what an injection is and how to avoid it ;)

Comment: I didn't say using mysqli makes it safe. I said using real escape string does

Comment: There is no reason for not using MySQLi with prepared statements.

Comment: And `mysql` has the exact same feature, it's nothing "REALLY cool" about `mysqli`. [`mysql_real_escape_string`](http://php.net/mysql-real-escape-string)

Comment: Oh my it must be Sunday. The SO Nazis have nothing better to do than troll for ego boosts...

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol yes nothing REALLY cool about mysqli except that it's not deprecated and is still maintained code...

Comment: Niet used Troll! It's super-effective! Niet's EGO rose! ... yeah, no.

Comment: @AMR MySQL_* library is just as secure as MySQLi, it just depends on your knowledge of SQL injection, it's pretty well summed up on the answer of a question I posted. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14311686/properly-escaping-with-mysqli-query-over-prepared-statements

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that mysql regocnizes '&' as AND. Check this out:

```
$content = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['content']); 
$sql = "insert into contents (column) values('$content')";
mysql_query($sql);
```

Comment: No, `mysql_query()` takes the last opened connection by default. Read the documentation: http://php.net/mysql_query

Comment: +1 for adressing the issue rather than "covering it up" by using a different library.

Comment: i used $content=mysql_real_escape_string($content) also, but it was in vain

Comment: @rosemary But remember to name the column.