# How to add Alphabetical pagination on the page

Tags: php, mysql

I'm new to php & developing a page where i want to fetch data from db & the pagination should be in alphabetical format. i.e A|B|C| .... On click of A it should display names starting with A only. Currently i'm just using LIMIT function.
Please Help !

```
<?php
     $host="localhost"; // Host name 
     $username="root"; // Mysql username 
     $password=""; // Mysql password 
     $db_name="testmra"; // Database name  
     // Connect to server and select databse.
     $conn=mysqli_connect($host,$username,$password) or die("cannot connect"); 
     mysqli_select_db($conn,$db_name);
     $sql = "SELECT * FROM newuser WHERE role='User' ORDER BY name asc LIMIT 15";
     $query = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);

     echo "<table border='1' id='mytable' width='100%'>
         <tr><th colspan='9' align='center'><h2>User Details</h2></th></tr>
         <tr bgcolor='grey'>
             <th width='25%'>Full Name</th>
             <th width='25%'>Department</th>
             <th width='25%'>EmailId</th>
             <th width='25%'>Username</th>
         </tr>";
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query))
        {
          echo "<tr>";
          echo "<td align='center'>" . $row['name']. "</td>";
          echo "<td align='center'>" . $row['department']. "</td>";
          echo "<td align='center'>" . $row['emailid'] . "</td>";
          echo "<td align='center'>" . $row['username'] . "</td>";
          echo "</tr>";
        }
     echo "</table>";
     mysqli_close($conn);   
?>
```

Comment: I didn't downvote you, but I am tempted to do this because you omitted so much critical information needed to give a solid answer.

Comment: Sir what critical information i have missed out ?

Comment: You omitted any information about the `newuser` table, including which column needs to be sorted alphabetically, for starters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    <?php
     $host="localhost"; // Host name 
     $username="root"; // Mysql username 
     $password=""; // Mysql password 
     $db_name="testmra"; // Database name  
     // Connect to server and select databse.

     $conn=mysqli_connect($host,$username,$password) or die("cannot connect"); 
     mysqli_select_db($conn,$db_name);
     if(isset($_GET['get'])){
       $get = mysqli_real_escape_string($_GET['get']);
     }else{
      $get = '';
     }
     $sql = "SELECT * FROM newuser WHERE role='User' AND name LIKE '$get%' ORDER BY name asc LIMIT 15";
     $query = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);

     echo "<table border='1' id='mytable' width='100%'>
         <tr><th colspan='9' align='center'><h2>User Details</h2></th></tr>
         <tr bgcolor='grey'>
             <th width='25%'>Full Name</th>
             <th width='25%'>Department</th>
             <th width='25%'>EmailId</th>
             <th width='25%'>Username</th>
         </tr>";
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query))
        {
          echo "<tr>";
          echo "<td align='center'>" . $row['name']. "</td>";
          echo "<td align='center'>" . $row['department']. "</td>";
          echo "<td align='center'>" . $row['emailid'] . "</td>";
          echo "<td align='center'>" . $row['username'] . "</td>";
          echo "</tr>";
        }
     echo "</table>";
     mysqli_close($conn);   
?>
<?php
$alphas = range('A', 'Z');
 foreach ($alphas as $key) {?>
<a href="answer.php?get=<?php  echo $key  ?>"><?php echo $key ?></a>
<?php }?>
```

using this you will get every alphabets so call it using ajax and you will get your alphabets using get method. Make new page answer.php for this code.

Comment: Sir just 1 question i.e How can i just call data starting with A whenever page is called ? Because right now it's showing all the entries from the database when the page is called

Comment: Please check it your query in MYSQL "SELECT * FROM newuser WHERE role='User' AND name LIKE 'A%' ORDER BY name asc LIMIT 15" ; You will get more detail here for like statement for mysql http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-like-clause.htm

Comment: Sir LIMIT will display first 15 rows from db & it's displaying data starting with B & c as well

Comment: LIKE 'A%' is only displaying values with A on click of any other alphabet

Comment: are you getting $Get value in sql or not?

Comment: $get = mysqli_real_escape_string($_GET['get']); I  forget to write underscore.

Comment: Sir i edited that long time back. I want to display names starting with A when the page is load & then display names according to the alphabets selected

Comment: can we get any solution for my query regarding the loading of page & other alphabet ?

Comment: you can call it using ajax.

Comment: How can i do it using AJAX ?

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to add this as a comment to the accepted answer but I don't have enough reputation to do so yet, sorry!

The answer is good, but I would strongly discourage placing variables inside a SQL statement, despite escaping the string before inserting it, it's still a potential risk.

[StackOverflow: Preventing SQL injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

The above link explains in excellent detail how to deal with this matter properly. A very worthwhile read for anyone involved in SQL at any level.

Comment: Can you check correctly? i used mysqli_real_escape_string. so its prevent mysql injections.

Comment: [Why prepared statements are better than escaping](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4771984/are-dynamic-mysql-queries-with-sql-escaping-just-as-secure-as-prepared-statements)

Comment: Ankit, I'd recommend leaving Shashikant's answer as the accepted answer as it is a full working solution. Mine is just a security ammendment. An up vote would be nice if you feel it is useful but it is not a full answer so should not be accepted

Comment: yes i know that @darren thanks for suggesting issues about sql injections.

Comment: @DarrenH vote up is not possible because i don't have enough reputation.