# MySQLi multi_query Security Precautions

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am setting up a couple of MySQLi multi_query function. I know you can't use prepared statements with multi_query, so I wanted to know what security precautions is recommended to use with muti_query.

real_escape_string()?

Comment: Input escaping is not a precaution, it's a requirement for producing a valid query that will execute at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pretty much yes. Especially given, that multi_query() allows for '[exploits of a mum](http://xkcd.com/327/)' type of injection. So yeah:

1. Escape strings
2. Cast inetgers to integers and floats to floats
3. If possible, assign your application privileges to SELECT, UPDATE, INSERT and DELETE only.

Answer (score 1):

In fact, [mysqli_]real_escape_string() has nothing to do with security. It's more like syntax formatter.

For the complete guide on securing queries refer to this my answer:
[In PHP when submitting strings to the database should I take care of illegal characters using htmlspecialchars() or use a regular expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2993027/in-php-when-submitting-strings-to-the-db-should-i-take-care-of-illegal-characters/2995163#2995163)