# What do I need to do to santize data from textarea to be fed to mysql database?

Tags: php, mysql, html

Well, the title is my question.  Can anybody give me a list of things to do to sanitize my data before entering to mysql database using php, especially if the data contains html tags?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on a lot of things. If you don't want to accept any HTML, that makes it a whole lot easier, run it through `strip_tags()` first to remove all the HTML from it. After that it's much safer. If you do want to accept some HTML, you can selectively keep some tags from it with the same function, just add in the tags to keep after. eg: `strip_tags($string_to_sanitize, '<p><div>'); // Keeps only <p> and <div> tags`.

As for inserting into a database, it's always best to sanitize **anything** before inserting into the database; adopting a "don't trust anybody" mentality will save you a lot of trouble. Preventing against SQL injection is fairly straightforward, this is the method I use:

```
$q = sprintf("INSERT INTO table_name (string_field, int_field) VALUES ('%s', %d);",
             mysql_real_escape_string($values['string']),
             mysql_real_escape_string($values['number']));

$result = mysql_query($q, $connection)
```

Generally once you open the door for allowing HTML in, you'll have a whole deal of things to worry about (there are some great articles on defending from XSS out there). If you want to test for XSS vulnerabilities, try the examples on http://ha.ckers.org/xss.html. There are some they have there that you would probably never even consider, so give it a look!

Also, if you are accepting specific types of input (eg: numbers, emails, boolean values) try using the inbuilt `filter_var()` function in PHP. They have a bunch of inbuilt types to validate data against (http://www.php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.validate.php), as well as a number of filters to sanitize your data (http://www.php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.sanitize.php).

Generally, accepting any input is like opening a Pandora's Box, and while you'll probably never be able to block 100% of the weaknesses (people are always looking to find a way in), you can block the common ones to save you headaches.

Finally remember to sanitize ALL external data. Just because you make a dropdown input doesn't mean some shady person can't send their own data instead!

Comment: it's a little unclear what you're saying about `strip_tags` optional second parameter.  It should contain a list of tags that are ok to leave in the string. Everything else will be stripped.  So in your example, `strip_tags($string_to_sanitize, '<script><p>');` it will strip out all tags except <p> and <script>.

Comment: @Jazzerus Thanks for pointing that out, I skipped over explaining that a bit! I've updated it to show your explanation

Answer (score 1):

Use mysql_real_escape_string();

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO table(col) VALUES('".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['data']."')");
```

Comment: This will only strip out characters that are unsafe to MySQL, but will not strip out any XSS or HTML that breaks a site.

Comment: Following up on berkes, do not allow script tags. and never but never allow php evaluation of the inserted text (I have seen this before)

Comment: Ofcourse, but as OP stated, he want's to prepare data for database insertion. You should strip out HTML etc. only when outputting data to user. You should use striptags or htmlspecialchars or even HTMLPurify to make the output safe.

Comment: berkes comment above is very misleading - and pity the fool who voted it up. You should always change the representation of data leaving your PHP using the **appropriate** method for the medium it is being written to - the answer above is correct in every way. But when you come to write the data to the browser it should be escaped using htmlentities(). If you want to allow some HTML, use strip_tags() - when you OUTPUT IT TO THE BROWSER

Answer (score 1):

You should use [prepared statements](http://www.petefreitag.com/item/356.cfm) when inserting data into the database, not any sort of escaping.  (PHP manual: prepared statements in [pdo](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) and [mysqli](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php).)

Sanitization for HTML output should, as mentioned by others, happen when you go to take data *out* of the database and merge it into a page, not before.

Answer (score 0):

Turn off `register_globals` and `magic_quotes`, use [mysql_real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) on any string coming from the user before placing it into your query.

Answer (score 0):

Of course mysql_real_escape_string
When dealing with any kind of input start from the I won't allow anything stand point and whitelist only that deemed to be acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

On insert you need to make sure that the data is MySQL-escaped. For this, use [mysql_real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php).

Before showing the data you will need to strip out unsafe HTML and/or JavaScript code. Many people choose to store the sanitised version in the database. Other prefer to strip the ugly HTML from the string before rendering.

You do this in PHP with some filtering. an example is the Drupal [filter_xss](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--filter--filter.module/function/filter_xss/6) function:

```
function filter_xss($string, $allowed_tags = array('a', 'em', 'strong', 'cite', 'code', 'ul', 'ol', 'li', 'dl', 'dt', 'dd')) {
  // Only operate on valid UTF-8 strings. This is necessary to prevent cross
  // site scripting issues on Internet Explorer 6.
  if (!drupal_validate_utf8($string)) {
    return '';
  }
  // Store the input format
  _filter_xss_split($allowed_tags, TRUE);
  // Remove NUL characters (ignored by some browsers)
  $string = str_replace(chr(0), '', $string);
  // Remove Netscape 4 JS entities
  $string = preg_replace('%&\s*\{[^}]*(\}\s*;?|$)%', '', $string);

  // Defuse all HTML entities
  $string = str_replace('&', '&amp;', $string);
  // Change back only well-formed entities in our whitelist
  // Decimal numeric entities
  $string = preg_replace('/&amp;#([0-9]+;)/', '&#\1', $string);
  // Hexadecimal numeric entities
  $string = preg_replace('/&amp;#[Xx]0*((?:[0-9A-Fa-f]{2})+;)/', '&#x\1', $string);
  // Named entities
  $string = preg_replace('/&amp;([A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9]*;)/', '&\1', $string);

  return preg_replace_callback('%
    (
    <(?=[^a-zA-Z!/])  # a lone <
    |                 # or
    <!--.*?-->        # a comment
    |                 # or
    <[^>]*(>|$)       # a string that starts with a <, up until the > or the end of the string
    |                 # or
    >                 # just a >
    )%x', '_filter_xss_split', $string);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

well, there is not too much to do while we're talking of *inserting data from textarea to mysql database.*

For the strings placed into query, Mysql requirements are not so complicated.
Only 2 rules to follow:

- inserted data should be surrounded by quotes.
- some special character in the data should be escaped.

Note that this operation has nothing to do with security. It's syntax requirements.

Assuming you're adding quotes already, the only thing you have to add is escaping. Depends on your encoding, you can use addslashes or mysql_escape_string or mysql_real_escape_string functions.

However, other parts of query require more attention. If you're curious, refer to my earlier answer with complete guide: [In PHP when submitting strings to the database should I take care of illegal characters using htmlspecialchars() or use a regular expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2993027/in-php-when-submitting-strings-to-the-db-should-i-take-care-of-illegal-characters/2995163#2995163)

HTML tags has nothing to do with database and require no special attention.

However, for displaying data from untrusted source, some precautions should be taken. It was described in this topic already, only I have to add is you can't trust to strip_tags when used with second parameter.

Answer (score -3):

You can use mysql_real_escape_string, you can also use htmlentities with addslashes... or you can use all 3 together also...

Comment: Should be careful when using all these together. addslashes is past, and it doesn't fully protect you.

Comment: yes that's why i did not tell to use addslashes alone... i told to use mysql_real_escape_string or use htmlentities with addslashes... so there is nothing like that you use only addslashes...

Comment: So if you got my point and think its ok now for you then remove your -1 from the voting... thanks

Comment: It is NOT ok now. nothing bad in addslashes but using all 3 together is ridiculous.

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel addslashes is not ok, it doesn't handle well some unicode charset and it has been proven in the past that it can still be vulnerable.

Comment: @HoLy yup, but nobody is using these rare encodings nowadays I believe.