# what are the best practices to prevent sql injections

Tags: php, sql, sql-injection

I have done some research and still confused, This is my outcome of that research. Can someone please comment and advise to how I can make these better or if there is a rock solid implementation already out there I can use?

Method 1:

```
array_map('trim', $_GET);
array_map('stripslashes', $_GET);
array_map('mysql_real_escape_string', $_GET);
```

Method 2:

```
function filter($data) {
    $data = trim(htmlentities(strip_tags($data)));

    if (get_magic_quotes_gpc())
        $data = stripslashes($data);

    $data = mysql_real_escape_string($data);

    return $data;
}

foreach($_GET as $key => $value) {
    $data[$key] = filter($value);
}
```

Comment: Your example code in method 1 will not work unless you assign the arrays back (otherwise it's actually a passable lazy solution). And in method 2 the undoing of magic quotes should occur first. Where did you find the silly code?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Both methods you show are not recommendable

Blanket "sanitizing" data is counter-productive, because data needs to be sanitised in different ways depending on how it is going to be used: Using it in a database query needs different sanitation from outputting it in HTML, or from using it as parameters in a command line call, etc. etc.

The best way to do sanitation is immediately before the data is being used. That way, it is easy for the programmer to see whether all data is actually getting sanitized.

If you use the `mysql_*` family of functions, do a `mysql_real_escape_string()` on every argument you use in a query:

```
$safe_name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["name"]);
$safe_address = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["address"]);

$result = mysql_query ("INSERT INTO table VALUES '$safe_name', '$safe_address'");
```

If you use the [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) families of functions, you can make use of parametrized queries, which eliminate most of the SQL injection woes - all everyday ones at any rate.

It is perfectly possible to write safe queries with `mysql_*`, and it is also perfectly possible to introduce a security hole in a PDO query, but if you are starting from scratch, consider using PDO or mysqli straight away.

Use `strip_tags()` only if you are planning to output user entered data in HTML; note that you need to do an additional `htmlspecialchars()` to reliably prevent XSS attacks.

The only blanket sanitation method that has some merit is the

```
 if (get_magic_quotes_gpc())
    $data = stripslashes($data);
```

call which filters out the layer of escaping added by the now-deprecated "magic quotes" feature of earlier versions of PHP.

Comment: I'd vote you up 1 million times if I could. PDO and parameters FTW. (sad that so many people STILL don't know this)

Comment: i;m somewhat in the learning stages with using advanced functions. I have never been introduced to PDO so i can't comment on why I haven't used it it. I tried sqli but some of my queries don't run with it on. Let me take a look at PDO and see if i can make heads or tails from it.

Comment: @s2xi yeah. It's perfectly possible to write safe queries with `mysql_*` but both PDO and mysqli have a number of advantages over it, so if at all possible, it won't hurt to get familiar with them.

Comment: @Cfreak well, I'd put it somewhat different. Many people STILL don't know about prepared statements and EVEN MORE people knows it perfectly, telling everyone to use it, *while never tried it themselves,* lol ;)

Comment: I am thinking of downvoting your answer, because given example covers string arguments only.

Comment: @Cfreak and "consider using PDO **or** mysqli" is a sign of that. If someone is using one of these libraries, they no doubt have an opinion what to choose. Or, in other words, only PDO should be mentioned.

Comment: [Here](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.overview.php) is a good comparison between mysql_*, mysqli and PDO.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is enough (EDIT: with $data we mean here e.g. one text field from a form, `$_POST['example']` etc):

```
if (get_magic_quotes_gpc())
    $data = stripslashes($data);

$data = mysql_real_escape_string($data);
```

I usually do the first when receiving the $_POST or $_GET data (before input testing) and the latter right before - or during - composing of the sql query.

Additionaly trim it, if you want (maybe you don't always want that). However the best solution would be using some libraries for working with database.

Answer (score 0):

You can either:

- Escape all user input supposed for the DB using mysql_real_escape_string (or the mysqli_variant)
- Use prepared statements (with mysqli_ or PDO)

Note that you should turn off magic_quotes if possible. If it's on, just use stripslashes (like in your example) as it's deprecated and you should not rely on it.

Also note that you should not do this for data which is not supposed to be inserted into the database as it's completely useless.

Comment: right, I have a check to see if magic_quotes is turned on, if not then use mysql_real_escape_string

Comment: No, you should not. magic_quotes() uses the addslashes() function, which doesn't 100% prevent you from SQL injections. Here is a good article on it: http://shiflett.org/blog/2006/jan/addslashes-versus-mysql-real-escape-string

Comment: What is the difference between "Escape all user input" and magic quotes?

Comment: Sorry, I meant user input supposed to be entered into the database. Not just any user input.

Comment: What about non-user input but something already being on the server or database?

Comment: What about non-quoted numbers like those going to LIMIT clause, e.g. `LIMIT $offset`?

Answer (score 0):

I like type-casting whenever you're dealing with `int`s;
e.g.

```
$id=(int)$_GET['id'];
if($id<1){//I generally don't pass around 0 or negative numbers
    //Injection Attempt
    die('Go Away');
}
//Continue with the number I **know** is a number
```

Comment: what if I id larger than 1? if in this case id would be the id of a user

Comment: @s2xi then everything is fine and there is no need for further anti-injection safety measures as far as that variable

Answer (score -1):

Well, among your codes only mysql_real_escape_string() function is SQL injection related. However, being completely misplaced.
And it's not enough.

In fact, this function should be used with quoted strings only.
And it's useless for the everything else. So, in any other case other precautions should be taken.

For the complete explanation see my earlier answer: [In PHP when submitting strings to the database should I take care of illegal characters using htmlspecialchars() or use a regular expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2993027/in-php-when-submitting-strings-to-the-db-should-i-take-care-of-illegal-characters/2995163#2995163)

All other functions you're using have no relation to SQL at all.
Note that using both strip_tags and htmlentities is redundant. and htmlentities is obsolete.
I'd use only `htmlspecialchars()` instead of these two, and not before inserting into database but right before sending it to browser.