# How to Make PHP Pagination Start on Page 1 Rather Than Page 0?

Tags: php, pdo, pagination

I've been working with a basic PHP/PDO pagination script I found online.

I've got it customized to my needs (I just need to do some basic layout work); the only thing that's left is getting the pagination to work the same way as every other professional website. And by that I mean getting the pagination to start on page 1 rather than page 0. Have you ever heard of "page 0"? I sure haven't! (Edit: I use a modified version of this script on my website and use an .htaccess file that changes the URL of page 0, index.php?start=0, to /page/0/. Upon reflection, I can now appreciate the logic of having the URL of the first page contain "start=0," since Google does the same thing. Nevertheless, this question stands because, unlike Google, this script suggests there's a page 0.)

Here are the relevant files:

configuration.php

```
<?php
   // define database related variables
   $database = 'db';
   $host = 'hostname';
   $user = 'username';
   $pass = 'password';

   // try to connect to database
   $db = new PDO("mysql:dbname={$database};host={$host};port={3306}", $user, $pass);

   if(!$db){

      echo "Error in database connection";
   }
?>
```

data.php

```
<?php 
    //include configuration file
    require 'configuration.php';

    $start = 0;  $per_page = 4;
    $page_counter = 0;
    $next = $page_counter + 1;
    $previous = $page_counter - 1;
    
    if(isset($_GET['start'])){
     $start = $_GET['start'];
     $page_counter =  $_GET['start'];
     $start = $start *  $per_page;
     $next = $page_counter + 1;
     $previous = $page_counter - 1;
    }
    // query to get messages from messages table
    $q = "SELECT * FROM students LIMIT $start, $per_page";
    $query = $db->prepare($q);
    $query->execute();

    if($query->rowCount() > 0){
        $result = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    }
    // count total number of rows in students table
    $count_query = "SELECT * FROM students";
    $query = $db->prepare($count_query);
    $query->execute();
    $count = $query->rowCount();
    // calculate the pagination number by dividing total number of rows with per page.
    $paginations = ceil($count / $per_page);
?>
```

index.php

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Pagination</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php include_once 'data.php'; ?>
        <div class="table-responsive" style="width: 600px; border: 1px solid black; margin: 10px;">
            <table class="table table-striped" class="table table-hover">
                <thead class="table-info">
                 <th scope="col" class="bg-primary" >Id</th>
                 <th scope="col" class="bg-primary">First Name</th>
                 <th scope="col" class="bg-primary">Last Name</th>
                 <th scope="col" class="bg-primary">Email</th>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                <?php 
                    foreach($result as $data) { 
                        echo '<tr>';
                        echo '<td>'.$data['id'].'</td>';
                        echo '<td>'.$data['first_name'].'</td>';
                        echo '<td>'.$data['last_name'].'</td>';
                        echo '<td>'.$data['email'].'</td>';
                        echo '</tr>';
                    }
                 ?>
                </tbody>
            </table>
            <center>
            <ul class="pagination">
            <?php
                if($page_counter == 0){
                    echo "<li><a href=?start='0' class='active'>0</a></li>";
                    for($j=1; $j < $paginations; $j++) { 
                      echo "<li><a href=?start=$j>".$j."</a></li>";
                   }
                }else{
                    echo "<li><a href=?start=$previous>Previous</a></li>"; 
                    for($j=0; $j < $paginations; $j++) {
                     if($j == $page_counter) {
                        echo "<li><a href=?start=$j class='active'>".$j."</a></li>";
                     }else{
                        echo "<li><a href=?start=$j>".$j."</a></li>";
                     } 
                  }if($j != $page_counter+1)
                    echo "<li><a href=?start=$next>Next</a></li>"; 
                } 
            ?>
            </ul>
            </center>    
        </div>  
    </body>
</html>
```

I think this might just be a matter of changing some 0's to 1's. I've already tried some combinations using this method, but I'm not sure what I'm doing.

The closest the article comes to mentioning how to change this pagination idiosyncrasy is by saying, "on the first page the page counter is 0, which is stored in $page_counter." So someone, such as myself, might conclude you only need to change the value of that variable to 1. If only it was that easy!

Comment: Just find yourself another article. this one makes no sense at all.

Comment: Too many variables which serves no purpose at the end result.

Comment: What have you tried to make it work? Why not start by adjusting the line with `echo "<li><a href=?start='0' class='active'>0</a></li>"` ?

Answer (score -1):

Here is how I would modify this (I don't have a way to test this so there might be some bugs):
PHP:

```
<?php 
    //include configuration file
    require 'configuration.php';

    $start = 0;
    $per_page = 4;
    $page_counter = 1;
    $next = $page_counter + 1;
    $previous = $page_counter - 1;
    
    if(isset($_GET['start'])){
     // $start = $_GET['start'];
     $page_counter = (int) $_GET['start'];
     $start = ($page_counter - 1) *  $per_page;
     $next = $page_counter + 1;
     $previous = $page_counter - 1;
    }
    // query to get messages from messages table
    $q = "SELECT * FROM students LIMIT $start, $per_page";
    $query = $db->prepare($q);
    $query->execute();

    if($query->rowCount() > 0){
        $result = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    }
    // count total number of rows in students table
    // Feels like doing "SELECT COUNT(*) as qty FROM students" may save some memory for the script as in this case you won't be loading entire table into your PDO library but just the total number of records value.
    $count_query = "SELECT * FROM students";
    $query = $db->prepare($count_query);
    $query->execute();
    $count = $query->rowCount();
    // calculate the pagination number by dividing total number of rows with per page.
    $paginations = ceil($count / $per_page);
?>
```

Html:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Pagination</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php include_once 'data.php'; ?>
        <div class="table-responsive" style="width: 600px; border: 1px solid black; margin: 10px;">
            <table class="table table-striped" class="table table-hover">
                <thead class="table-info">
                 <th scope="col" class="bg-primary" >Id</th>
                 <th scope="col" class="bg-primary">First Name</th>
                 <th scope="col" class="bg-primary">Last Name</th>
                 <th scope="col" class="bg-primary">Email</th>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                <?php 
                    foreach($result as $data) { 
                        echo '<tr>';
                        echo '<td>'.$data['id'].'</td>';
                        echo '<td>'.$data['first_name'].'</td>';
                        echo '<td>'.$data['last_name'].'</td>';
                        echo '<td>'.$data['email'].'</td>';
                        echo '</tr>';
                    }
                 ?>
                </tbody>
            </table>
            <center>
            <ul class="pagination">
            <?php
                if($page_counter > 1)
                    echo "<li><a href=?start=$previous>Previous</a></li>";
                for($j=1; $j <= $paginations; $j++) {
                  if($j == $page_counter) {
                     echo "<li><a href=?start=$j class='active'>". $j ."</a></li>";
                  } else {
                     echo "<li><a href=?start=$j>". $j ."</a></li>";
                  } 
                }
                if($page_counter < $paginations)
                    echo "<li><a href=?start=$next>Next</a></li>"; 
            ?>
            </ul>
            </center>    
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for the response. I believe your corrections would change the links, but not not the URLs. This was my fault for not being more specific. Basically, I want the URL of the first page to be something like "index.php?start=1" rather than "index.php?start=0." Of course, "1" should also be the link for the first page.

Comment: I see. You will have to modify your backend logic as well as the view. Essentially just shift  all the numbers up by 1. Then in your query do something like `"SELECT * FROM students LIMIT" .  $start -1 . ", $per_page"`

Comment: Thanks again. It sounds like you know what to do. I'm still learning Stack Overflow (not to mention PHP), but do you know if you can edit your answer? If so, could you make all the edits and add the `// Updated this line` comments where applicable again? With that said, I kind of do understand the logic of having the URLs start with "index.php?start=0." Google does something similar. But my URLs look like this: "/page/0/". So I think you can kind of understand why I want 1 to be the first page's URL.

Comment: Made some edits. Updated quite a few lines so didn't put `// Updated this like` comment at all.

Comment: You're so close! There's just one bug: On the first page (index.php or index.php?start=1), if there is more than one page, it always displays the total number of pages _minus 1_. For example: if there's 2 pages, it only shows page 1; if there's 3 pages, it only shows page 1 and page 2; if there's 4 pages, it only shows pages 1, 2, and 3. If there's 1 page, it only shows page 1. Note that this is _only_ for index.php?start=1 or index.php. All the other pages seem flawless. If you can figure this out, I will be so happy!

Comment: :) try to change this line `for($j=2; $j < $paginations; $j++) {` to read like `for($j=2; $j <= $paginations; $j++) {`. Updated the answer as well.

Comment: Consider that bug squashed! I did overlook one more bug (it might be in the original tutorial): On index.php or index.php?start=1, there is no "Next" link. I feel like I am nitpicking at this point.

Comment: That code is widely open for SQL injection and should never be used

Comment: Ok, optimized logic a little bit. Removed unnecessary conditions. As to sql injections, I think it is a valid concern and this is a sample snippet that probably needs to be revised before using it in production environment. In this particular case variables used in the query are calculated and there is no way they can have unsanitized contet.

Comment: Nico, I appreciate your advice. I have been a PHP noob for 18 years. Is there any quick fix for this risky code? Are the risks of SQL injection for this script still detrimental if I am just using this script for a blog, if there are no other tables in the database, and if the username and password in configuration.php are for a user with read-only privileges? The fact of the matter is I don't know if I'd be able to find a secure pagination script online. Furthermore, I wouldn't even have any way of knowing which scripts were secure.

Comment: Thank you, @farhodius. It works! Are you saying the updated script is now at least _more_ immune to SQL injection? Do you have any idea what would make it bulletproof? I see you added "(int)" to the line `$page_counter = (int) $_GET['start'];`. Is this what you were talking about in your last sentence? And does this "(int)" help prevent against SQL injection? If you make any more edits to the script, it would be nice if you left a comment here.

Comment: Nothing is bullet proof but if you change this line `$q = "SELECT * FROM students LIMIT $start, $per_page";` to read like `$q = "SELECT * FROM students LIMIT " . (int) $start . ", " . (int) $per_page;` it should take care of of any sql injection concerns for this particular code snippet. Overall you have to consider using parametrized queries. Not sure if your PDO library supports those. Feels like this turns into a blog discussion. I'm afraid we are violating stackoverflow.com best practices. Consider creating new question to tackle any sql injection concerns.

Comment: Sorry for writing again, but I think I found how to prevent SQL injection in this script. The key is parameterized queries. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30533982/php-pagination-security-regarding-int These are the changes I made: `$q = "SELECT * FROM students LIMIT " . (int) $start . ", " . (int) $per_page;` should be `$q = "SELECT * FROM students LIMIT ?, " . (int) $per_page;` and `$query->execute();` should be `$query->execute(array((int)$start));` @farhodius it might be a good idea to update your answer with this code and the code in your last comment.