# best way to escape data JS->PHP->MySQL and vice versa

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, escaping, encode

what functions i have to use to encode/decode/escape/stripslash data for following purposes?

1. when calling a PHP script from JS like: `page.php?data=don't_use_#_and_%_in_URL_params`
2. when a PHP script receive a parameter from JS like: `don%27t_use_%23_and_%25_in_URL_params`
3. when running a MySQL query from PHP with data previously received from JS to prevent MySQL injections (lets say i need to insert in database the following sequence of characters: ``` "``' ```)
4. when i need to compare in a MySQL statement a field value which contains ``` "``' ``` sequence with an expression
5. when i need to retrieve a field value from a MySQL table and the field contains ``` "``' ``` and i want to use it in a PHP eval() macrosubstitution
6. when i have to send data from PHP to JS in an AJAX response and it contains ``` "``' ``` characters
7. and finally i have to eval() previous respond in JS

something like this diagram:

JS(encode) --> (decode)PHP(encode) --> (decode?)MySQL(encode?) --> (decode)MySQL(encode) --> (decode)JS

if anyone have the time and pleasure to answer, or to correct me if i made any mistakes here, thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. [encodeURIComponent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent)
2. `$_GET`
3. [PDO bound parameters](http://bobby-tables.com/php.html)
4. [PDO bound parameters](http://bobby-tables.com/php.html) in a database. Otherwise it is just a string in PHP
5. No idea. You really should have asked a Question for each question you have. `eval` smells bad though.
6. Pick a data format and use appropriate encoding for that. [JSON](http://php.net/json_encode) is common.
7. The only time you should go near `eval()` is JS is when you are implementing a support for `json` in browsers without a native version (and you can use Crockford's json2.js for that). So don't.

Comment: 2. $_GET will never transform my JS encoded string "don%27t_use_%23_and_%25_in_URL_params" into "don't_use_#_and_%_in_URL_params" what i expect to receive in $_GET["data"]

Comment: Yes it will. PHP does The Right Thing for URL Encoded data when populating `$_GET`.

Answer (score 1):

1. escape()
2. No action required.
   3-4. Data source doesn't matter here. there are common rules for building the query, I am sure you know it all already. If not - refer to [this complete explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2993027/in-php-when-submitting-strings-to-the-db-should-i-take-care-of-illegal-characters/2995163#2995163).
3. **NEVER** do it. It's a hole of a skyscraper size in your application. Don't you see it?
4. json_encode()
5. eval? are you sure? why not to send data only while all codes already present in JS?