# Preventing SQL Injections

Tags: php, mysql, forms, sql-injection

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Best way to stop SQL Injection in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-stop-sql-injection-in-php)
>   [In PHP when submitting strings to the database should I take care of illegal characters using htmlspecialchars() or use a regular expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2993027/in-php-when-submitting-strings-to-the-database-should-i-take-care-of-illegal-char)

Yesterday I asked a question with regards to a script not working, whilst I in the end solved the issue myself. There was talk of SQL Injections risks.

So what I'm asking today is, with the code I have inserted below, how would one prevent SQL Injections?

So any advice of guidence. I know I can read the internet about SQL injections but there is so many conflicting articles on it, I don't know which is correct or not.

Here is the code, this is all put in a page of it's own lets say 'form-process.php' which the form then submits the data to e.g

```
<?
session_start(); 

$_SESSION['Title'] = stripslashes($_REQUEST['Title']); 
$_SESSION['ShortTitle'] = stripslashes($_REQUEST['Title']); 
$_SESSION['Category'] = stripslashes($_REQUEST['Category']); 
$_SESSION['Story'] = stripslashes($_REQUEST['Story']);
$_SESSION['FrontPage'] = stripslashes($_REQUEST['FrontPage']);
$_SESSION['imagefilename'] = ($_FILES['image']['name']); 

if (empty($_REQUEST['Title'])) { 
header("Location: ". $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] ."?message=0"); 
exit; 
} elseif (empty($_REQUEST['ShortTitle'])) { 
header("Location: ". $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] ."?message=1"); 
exit; 
} elseif (strlen($_REQUEST['Category']) < 1) {
header("Location: ". $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] ."?message=2"); 
exit;
} elseif (empty($_REQUEST['Story'])) { 
header("Location: ". $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] ."?message=3"); 
exit;  
} else { 

include("settings.php"); 
include("dbconnect.php"); 

if($_POST['btnSubmit'] == 'Publish'){
    $target = "../../../images/matchreports/uploaded/";
    $target = $target . time() . '-' . basename( $_FILES['image']['name']);
    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $target)){
    $image=time() . '-' . basename( $_FILES['image']['name']);      
    $newdate = $_POST['date_y'].''.$_POST['date_m'].''.$_POST['date_d'];
$SQL = "INSERT INTO " . $match_reports_table . " (Title,ShortTitle,Story,FrontPage,active,image,date,user_ip) VALUES('" . addslashes($_REQUEST['Title']) . "','" . addslashes($_REQUEST['ShortTitle']) . "','" . addslashes($_REQUEST['Story']) . "','" . addslashes($_REQUEST['FrontPage']) . "','" . addslashes(y) . "','$image','$newdate','" . addslashes($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']) . "')";
    $result = @mysql_query($SQL) or die("Error Publishing 1");

    header("Location: /cms/matchreports/index.php?message=4");  
    exit;

} else {

$newdate = $_POST['date_y'].''.$_POST['date_m'].''.$_POST['date_d'];    
$SQL = "INSERT INTO " . $match_reports_table . " (Title,ShortTitle,Story,FrontPage,active,date,user_ip) VALUES('" . addslashes($_REQUEST['Title']) . "','" . addslashes($_REQUEST['ShortTitle']) . "','" . addslashes($_REQUEST['Story']) . "','" . addslashes($_REQUEST['FrontPage']) . "','" . addslashes(n) . "','$newdate','" . addslashes($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']) . "')";
    $result = @mysql_query($SQL) or die("Error Publishing 2");

    header("Location: /cms/matchreports/index.php?message=5");  
    exit;}}

if($_POST['btnSubmit'] == 'Save draft'){
    $target = "../../../images/matchreports/uploaded/";
    $target = $target . time() . '-' . basename( $_FILES['image']['name']);
    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $target)){
    $image=time() . '-' . basename( $_FILES['image']['name']);      
    $newdate = $_POST['date_y'].''.$_POST['date_m'].''.$_POST['date_d'];
$SQL = "INSERT INTO " . $match_reports_table . " (Title,ShortTitle,Story,FrontPage,active,image,date,user_ip) VALUES('" . addslashes($_REQUEST['Title']) . "','" . addslashes($_REQUEST['ShortTitle']) . "','" . addslashes($_REQUEST['Story']) . "','" . addslashes($_REQUEST['FrontPage']) . "','" . addslashes(n) . "','$image','$newdate','" . addslashes($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']) . "')";
    $result = @mysql_query($SQL) or die("Error Saving Draft 1");

    header("Location: /cms/matchreports/index.php?message=6");  
    exit;

} else {

$newdate = $_POST['date_y'].''.$_POST['date_m'].''.$_POST['date_d'];    
$SQL = "INSERT INTO " . $match_reports_table . " (Title,ShortTitle,Story,FrontPage,active,date,user_ip) VALUES('" . addslashes($_REQUEST['Title']) . "','" . addslashes($_REQUEST['ShortTitle']) . "','" . addslashes($_REQUEST['Story']) . "','" . addslashes($_REQUEST['FrontPage']) . "','" . addslashes(n) . "','$newdate','" . addslashes($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']) . "')";
    $result = @mysql_query($SQL) or die("Error Saving Draft 2");

    header("Location: /cms/matchreports/index.php?message=7");  
    exit;}}

if($_POST['btnSubmit'] == 'Publish changes'){
//This gets all the other information from the form
$newdate = $_POST['date_y'].''.$_POST['date_m'].''.$_POST['date_d'];
$SQL = "UPDATE " . $match_reports_table . " SET Title='" . addslashes($_REQUEST['Title']) . "',ShortTitle='" . addslashes($_REQUEST['ShortTitle']) . "',Story='" . addslashes($_REQUEST['Story']) . "',Category='" . addslashes($_REQUEST['Category']) . "',FrontPage='" . addslashes($_REQUEST['FrontPage']) . "',active = '" . y . "',date='$newdate' WHERE ID=" . $_REQUEST['ID'] . "";
$result = @mysql_query($SQL) or die("Error Updating News"); 

header("Location: /cms/matchreports/index.php?message=8");
exit;}

if($_POST['btnSubmit'] == 'Publish draft to website'){
//This gets all the other information from the form
$newdate = $_POST['date_y'].''.$_POST['date_m'].''.$_POST['date_d'];
$SQL = "UPDATE " . $match_reports_table . " SET Title='" . addslashes($_REQUEST['Title']) . "',ShortTitle='" . addslashes($_REQUEST['ShortTitle']) . "',Story='" . addslashes($_REQUEST['Story']) . "',Category='" . addslashes($_REQUEST['Category']) . "',FrontPage='" . addslashes($_REQUEST['FrontPage']) . "',active = '" . y . "',date='$newdate' WHERE ID=" . $_REQUEST['ID'] . "";
$result = @mysql_query($SQL) or die("Error Updating News"); 

header("Location: /cms/matchreports/index.php?message=9");
exit;}

if($_POST['btnSubmit'] == 'Save changes to draft'){
//This gets all the other information from the form
$newdate = $_POST['date_y'].''.$_POST['date_m'].''.$_POST['date_d'];
$SQL = "UPDATE " . $match_reports_table . " SET Title='" . addslashes($_REQUEST            ['Title']) . "',ShortTitle='" . addslashes($_REQUEST['ShortTitle']) . "',Story='" . addslashes($_REQUEST['Story']) . "',Category='" . addslashes($_REQUEST['Category']) . "',FrontPage='" . addslashes($_REQUEST['FrontPage']) . "',active = '" . n . "',date='$newdate' WHERE ID=" . $_REQUEST['ID'] . "";
$result = @mysql_query($SQL) or die("Error Updating News"); 

header("Location: /cms/matchreports/index.php?message=10");
exit;}

}?>
```

Comment: H.O.R.R.I.B.L.E code!

Comment: one thing you really need is to get rid of TONS of repeated code.

Comment: you'll get no less conflicting answers as well :)

Comment: Any time you create SQL code via string concatenation of user supplied input, you are at risk of SQL injection attacks. The best way to avoid this risk is by using prepared/parameterized queries. I'm marking this as a dupe, because other questions exist that address this very same issue.

Comment: I can't believe some developers code like this.... Incredible.

Comment: @Jamie: We all have to learn somehow. At least OP has registered that there might be a risk and asked a community about how to improve. Denigration is not a kind approach.

Comment: @spender however, sometimes we can't avoid concatenation. So, we have to learn how to live with it

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel: could you expand on this? The whole point of parameterized queries is to mitigate the risk.

Comment: Indeed, my apologies. I should have said, I can't believe people who do development as their day job for a company code like this. Sorry, OP.

Comment: @spender prepared statements have no support for the identifiers for example. So, you have to concatenate if there is a field name to be added into query dynamically

Comment: `$_POST['btnSubmit'] == 'Publish'` Don't check for post-button-values if you plan to have a translation of that site someday…

Answer (score 6):

Use PDO and [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php).

Comment: +1 for suggesting prepared statements

Comment: prepared statements is not sufficient to prevent certain SQL injections and PDO is quite ugly. However, for the plain inserts it's okay

Comment: Do you have a better answer before downvoting mine?

Comment: pdo does not prevent injections, but prepeared statements you can use also with mysqli. Also prepeared statement are slower. Also you cannot create prepeared statements with varible amount of data like WHERE id IN (1,5,9,12,45,67) where ids are from array.

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel - how PDO is ugly?

Comment: @cthulhu it makes you write tons of useless code like binding values, preparing queries and stuff.

Comment: @Shrapnel you could build an interface class for it that makes common stuff a little bit easier and less lines of code. I think the methods behind it are really good.

Comment: @Col. Sharpnel - why you consider preparing queries as "useless"? I don't really know how do **you** write your code with PDO, but I personally never got "tons" of code. I'd say it depends on the coder itself rather than on the tool.

Comment: @RijkvanWel just ignore Shrappers as he very rarely contributes [anything of value](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Troll_(Internet)) to comments on answers.

Comment: @cthulhu we were talking of *the* tool, aren't we?

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel - yes, and the "tool" called PDO is great. If you get "tons" of code while using PDO, you should probably think about what's wrong with you, rather than with the "tool" itself. Bad coder, can write an ugly code using with any "tool". But even if you're that kind of a coder, I guess it's better to write an ugly but a safe code with PDO rather than an ugly AND insecure code using OLD mysql library which hasn't been updated since the days of PHP 4.1 because all the work was concentrated around the PDO/mysqli extensions.

Comment: @cthulhu What if I am writing secure code without PDO and without preparing statements? :) And even more secure, as I have identifiers support while PDO haven't :-P However, you are right about using tools (but PDO makes me do more job while make it usable anyway ).

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel - What do you mean when you say "secure code"? A code without prepared statements? You are still vulnerable to a various attacks even when you use `mysql_real_escape_string`. I don't even talk about the fact that your beloved standard mysql library doesn't support stored procedures and multiple statements. And as I already mentioned, it's old, slower, and have less functionality than PDO/mysqli. What about "do more job" - complete bullshit. Have you ever heard about wrappers? Have you ever heard about object mapping? Likely, the problem is YOU in this case.

Comment: @cthulhu secure means no possibility for the injection. `You are still vulnerable to a various attacks` - no, I am not. I am pefectly secure. Just because my security based on knowledge and experience, not some religious gospels like "use PDO". `mysql library doesn't support stored procedures` - mysql does, that's enough for me; `it's slower` - I see no difference; `and have less functionality than PDO` - I can write anything myself. So to say `Have you ever heard about object mapping?` - I can map it with whatever I use. Good coder can write good code using any tool ;)

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel - yes you are. There are plenty of bugs related to this. Moreover, because `mysql_real_escape_string` depends on character encoding, which can be changed to a non utf-8 encoding, it can lead to serious problems. If you aren't familiar with PDO, that doesn't mean it is useless. Yeah, You can write anything by yourself (including the OM) and thereby reinvent the wheel. And you tell me PDO is complex? Ahh. Rewriting it with PHP will make it much slower and inefficient, so you can just kill yourself insted. So you'd better learn how to use PDO before you troll here.

Comment: @cthulhu please do me a favor. Would you please run this snippet of code exactly as it is in your usual background and paste it's output here?  `$dbh->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
try {
  $sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM users GROUP BY WHERE 1 = ?");
  $sth->execute(array("1"));
} catch (PDOException $e) {
  echo $e->getMessage();
}`. where $dbh is a PDO object. Based on your answer I will explain you my point.

Answer (score 4):

A simple, universal rule I like to apply is this:

*Always store data raw, and escape it for the appropriate application when needed.*

This means, get rid of nebulous `stripslashes()`, and:

- for *string* values in SQL statements, use the database's appropriate escape function, e.g. `mysqli_real_escape_string()`,
- for `system()`-type command names, use `escapeshellcmd()`, for arguments use `escapeshellarg()`,
- for manually assembling GET request URLs, use `urlencode()`, and finally
- for printing content in an HTML structure, use `htmlentities()`.

There's no point in blindly using some sort of mangling and hoping it'll filter out bad things. Be conscious of what you're doing, and do the appropriate thing at every step.

*Example:* To print a link with a user-provided GET parameter, you'd do

```
print("<a href='" . htmlentities($BASEURL . "?data=" . urlencode($untrusted)) . "'>click</a>");
```

*Important note:* For SQL queries, it is generally preferable to use *prepared statements* rather than building queries by hand. This is a different technology from what you're used to, so it's not the straight "how do I fix this" answer, but it is by far the better solution.

Comment: there are some other kinds of values to insert into query beside strings

Comment: I like the "always store data raw" rule. Is there an article or book that elaborates on this?

Comment: @Rijk: It comes from seeing too many questions on "how do I use regular expressions to parse my HTML" :-) Not a book that I know of, but it's just common sense I suppose... Store what you *mean*, not some arbitrary transformation of it.

Comment: Ok. I live by this rule myself too (after having fallen on my face a couple of times) - was just wondering if someone smart wrote something smart about it :)

Comment: I don't do PHP, but is `mysqli_real_escape_string` for real? Is there also a `mysqli_escape_string`? Madness.

Comment: @spender: it is - the "real" version takes the connection's character set into account and only works with an open connection, while the "unreal" version works sort of in the dark.

Comment: @spender it's not actually PHP but Mysql