# Where can I find a good coverage of standard Data Sanitization Techniques?

Tags: php, mysql, sanitization

I have three books on which being on PHP or PHP & MySQL one might reasonable expect to find some coverage of Data Sanitization, but I haven't had any luck. Is there a reliable resource online that covers the basics of cleaning your data up, both before putting it into a DB and before displaying it after pulling it from the DB?

Answer (score 1):

Well Stackoverflow is such a resource. Your question being asked twice a day.

I wrote a pretty decent answer on this topic earlier: [In PHP when submitting strings to the database should I take care of illegal characters using htmlspecialchars() or use a regular expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2993027/in-php-when-submitting-strings-to-the-database-should-i-take-care-of-illegal-char/2995163#2995163)

Long story short: for dynamic mysql query creation you have **four** different escaping cases:

- string data
- int data
- identifiers
- operators

and notorious PDO covers only **two** of them.

for the HTML htmlspecialchars with ENT_QUOTES is quite enough.
However, there are a dosen other cases, like filename sanitization, mail injection and such

Answer (score 0):

Chris Shifflet wrote a book on it called [Essential PHP Security](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/059600656X).

Answer (score 0):

Use PDO and [binding](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) or suitable [escape string function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) for mysql to input data.

Use [htmlspecialchars](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) with `ENT_QUOTES` and the correct charset on data to display for output.