# Validating links for sql injections in php

Tags: mysql, sql-injection

I just needed some help regarding validating links for sql injection automatically.

For instance:
There is a site so called as

http://www.example.com/news.php?id=13

After inserting quotation at the end we get an MySql error like this

http://www.example.com/news.php?id=13'

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '\' order by Sort DESC Limit 0,12' at line 1

So i was wondering is there any way by which i can check these links for errors automated. Like before the injected url execution it should show normal status but after injection it should show abnormal status.

NOTE: I am not talking about my website. I am developing an application online that will be free for developers for checking there site security.

Any help will be appreciated :)

Comment: How would you detect if the site threw an error? Any half-way decent production site would not be displaying server-side errors to the user, or only showing "sorry, something exploded" and no details.

Comment: This is sort of an ironic question, but snide remarks aside I think you should update your post with the actual query you're running. It might be a simple syntax error.

Comment: just check this site for instance                                     http://www.bonsaitrees.com/gallery.php?id=5 after putting a quotation at the end you get sql error...http://www.bonsaitrees.com/gallery.php?id=5'..... i was wondering if there is any way to capture this error

Comment: @NidaZubair, There is a lot of such applications on the internet.. Are you gonna give it as online or offline solution ?

Comment: @sh4nx0r...online solution...other applications are supposed to enter direct links but my application will require only simple url like http://www.example.com/

Comment: And that site you link is totally open to SQL injection, for example: http://www.bonsaitrees.com/gallery.php?id=5||1=1

Comment: Without seeing the code that you are trying to run it is hard to give you any concise advice but you should start by filtering your user input http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php and using prepared statements http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php to avoid errors such as this. I have assumed PHP but I am sure similar functions/methods exist whatever your language of choice.

Answer (score 0):

Validating has nothing to do with injections.

***Validating* and injection protection are completely different tasks.**

You may validate your data whatever way you like, but injection protection is completely different matter. It is data independent.

Your code have to be able to insert whatever data - links, numbers, HTML codes, binary objects - whatever. 
[I've explained the whole matter earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2995163/285587), so, I won't repeat myself.

As for the validation - you may check your links to be valid - with http:// in front and such. but again, it has nothing to do with injections.

> I am developing an application online that will be free for developers for checking there site security.

Gosh! Are you **sure** you are experienced enough?