# Are these steps enough to secure a site?

Tags: php, security

I am about to launch my website and security is important so i wanted to outline what I have done to secure the site.  Please correct me if I am wrong and if I need something else:

- To connect to our server, I have a two-factor authenitcation enabled via VPN.
- The site uses SSL
- Data is encrypted at rest.
- I have a log monitoring tool
- WHen users enter data into the database i use mysql_real_escape_string(); and when i display user data i use htmlspecialchars();
- Passwords are stored using md5 encryption.

  ```
       Sample insert query: 

       // I use these on every page
       $username = removeBadChars($_SESSION["username"]);
       $password = removeBadChars($_SESSION["password"]);

       //Sanitized data
       $_SESSION["username"] = $username;
       $_SESSION["password"] = $password;

       //Query to display 
       $sql = "select `User_name`, `User_id`, `User_kind` from `clientele` 
       where `username` =   '$username' AND `password`='$password'";
       $query = mysql_query($sql) or die ("Error: ".mysql_error());

        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){

    $name = htmlspecialchars($row['User_name']);
    $uid = htmlspecialchars($row['User_id']);
    $uis = htmlspecialchars($row['User_kind']);

        }
        mysql_free_result($query);



        //Insert Query

        $title = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['title']);
        $comment = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['comment']);

        $insert = "INSERT INTO table (Title, Comment)
        VALUES ('".$title."', '".$comment."')";

         $query = mysql_query($insert) or die ("Error: ".mysql_error());
  ```

Comment: You have a table named users where you store passwords in cleartext? If so, the answer to your question is an emphatic "no!".

Comment: no i just made the names up as i was tying right into it, just changed it so nobody else gets confused.  password fields are md5 encrypted. sorry about the confusion!

Comment: Read Jeff Atwood's most recent entry. (http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/) MD5 has been broken.

Comment: You should be using a sha-2 hashing algo and storing the passwords with a unique salt for each user.

Comment: Thanks. How about everything else i have posted above? Is that secure?

Comment: MD5 isn't "encryption". It might be better to leave the security design to a specialist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Use a stronger hash function (e.g. `sha256`)
2. Append a salt (random value for every user) to the password before hashing it
3. Use [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) (`MySQLi`) instead, to avoid the possibility of forgetting to escape data before entering it into the database
4. <del>Do **not** store user information in $_SESSION. Instead, store a session variable that means nothing to the outside world, changes every time someone logs in, and links to the user account.</del> - This only applies to cookies. *drinks some caffeine*
5. Be careful putting data from user in attribute values (e.g. `<span title="FULLNAME">`), as additional escaping is needed (quotes, spaces if not using quotes, etc)

***Note:** This list is not exhaustive. It only lists things I noticed that were wrong with the short snippets you provided.*

Comment: I agree for the most part, except your point about sessions. Session information are stored on the server, only a unique value used to identify sessions are stored on the client. You seem to be confusing regular cookies with sessions.

Answer (score -1):

For safety you should probably use a [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) or [`mysqli_` functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) and skip that old-school `mysql_` junk, it's no longer being developed. Here's how to use the PDO:

```
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=whatever', $username, $password);
$statement = $pdo->prepare('select `User_name`, `User_id`, `User_kind` from `users` 
 where `username` = :user AND `password`= AES_ENCRYPT(:pass,:user)');
$statement->bindParam(':user', $_GET['user']);
$statement->bindParam(':pass', $_GET['pass']);
$results = $statement->execute();
var_dump($results->fetchAll());
```

the parameters are much safer because when you [`bindParam`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php) it automagically validates. Others have mentioned using `md5` hashing, but there are plenty of [databases for "decoding"](http://md5.noisette.ch/) them and also rainbow table attacks, so they're not very secure. Here I'm using mysql's `AES_ENCRYPT` for the password, and using the username as the key for demonstration purposes, you'd probably want to generate your own key and store it somewhere, because you can `AES_DECRYPT` with that... There are libraries for better encryption you should check out, like [scrypt](http://www.tarsnap.com/scrypt.html).

Whatever you do, do not use [`addslashes()` it's insecure](http://shiflett.org/blog/2006/jan/addslashes-versus-mysql-real-escape-string)

On top of that you should look into securing your server's OS and Apache in other ways, like making not advertise version numbers and running apache as it's own users etc. Check out [the Open Web Security Project website](https://www.owasp.org) for tons of security info.

Comment: can you please provide at least one example to show why an "old-school mysql_ junk" is less secure than fashionable modern PDO? Thank you.

Comment: @YourCommonSense, JKirchartz is referring to the lack of prepared statements (you don't have to escape variables when you bind them to a statement). This is a benefit of both PDO (binds to `:somevar`) and MySQLi (binds to `?`). While you may think (and who knows, you might actually be able to do it) that you'll *always* escape variables before you put them into an SQL statement, prepared statements take away any doubt. For example, when hacking on a script and changing things quickly, it's common to simply escape at the end. However, this is **automatic** with prepared statements.

Comment: @bfrohs to create a custom mysql_ based db access library utilizing placeholders is a matter of a few hours. So, if you want to say that a placeholder is a good thing to use - I would agree with you. But saying that mysql ext is less secure than PDO is just not true

Comment: @YourCommonSense, it isn't necessarily that the MySQL extension is less secure, it's that it's easier to open up security holes on accident with the MySQL extension than with PDO or MySQLi. So while it's perfectly possible to be secure with plain old MySQL, it's easier to be secure (and harder not to be). This is especially true when a project is passed from one person to another, or is worked on by someone other than yourself (who may not know how write secure code, or is more forgetful than yourself).

Comment: @bfrohs `it isn't necessarily that the MySQL extension is less secure`. Thank you. I hope the author, whom you advocate, will agree with you. Also, I'd like to say that it's knowledge that can make you secure, not some magic wand. PDO just replaced the old idol, but understanding scarcely got improved.

Comment: anyone who don't want to write mysql_real_escape_string(), can write **a function** or even an own class to do all the job. A programmer can *create* tools for his own use, not only use realy-made ones.

Comment: @YourCommonSense Yes you can write tons of code to help, but then you'd have to write that code and use those libraries and you create your own cargo cult. Using open source projects mitigates risk because the hivemind ensures quality in the codebase (eventually) or the project dies. Also arguing everything doesn't mean you're clever, it means you're argumentative.

Comment: Well I assume your comment as something like "Thanks to your argumentative comments I've learned a lot while editing my answer" ;-)  Keep going. Say, mysql_real_escape_string(), as well as your beloved PDO prepared statements, is no more secure than addslashes() if you don't set encoding properly, and thus makes the same attack quite possible :)

Comment: @YourCommonSense If you have a better answer post it, not every post needs to be turned into community wiki.

Comment: Oh. I thought it would encourage you to learn more, nothing else. Writing more answers makes not a slightest sense because 1) it wont help the particular OP just because he is not ready to learn the proper answer. 2) there are already many proper answers written. 3) nobody will see them anyway because every good answer is buried under tons of trash.

Comment: @YourCommonSense I didn't learn more, I had to add alternate routes to appease your critique... 1) you must be a zen master, the teacher will reveal themselves when the student is ready to learn 2) in this case both of them 3) people upvote the better answers thus exhuming them