# How to convert this special sign in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, regex

I have saved strings in a MySQL database that contain symbol â€“. I would like to convert that to the correct symbol –. Do you have any idea what would be the easiest way to do it?

Comment: what language are you using to send it to mySql? is it Java..? and what is your mysql envoding is set to?  refer this guide: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10113355/correct-php-method-to-store-special-chars-in-mysql-db

Comment: PHP. I tried basic REPLACE() via PHP but so far it didn't work out. MySQL doesn't recognize the symbols.

Comment: replace will not work, but you need to set the proper encoding for your response before it sends to the mysql. if you refer to the link I gave, it has several solutions you can try out with PHP and how set the collation in mysql. again: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10113355/correct-php-method-to-store-special-chars-in-mysql-db

Comment: This will replace the symbol to zero in query : `select replace('dsâ€“','â€“','0');`  . use replace in MYSQL query instead of PHP

Comment: Encode and decode your string? Insert the decoded string value into the DB

Answer (score 0):

Don't look for the "easiest way"; you are likely continue to have trouble.

`â€“` id Mojibake for `–`.  `SELECT HEX(col), col FROM ...`, you should get `E28093`.  If so, then I'll explain one fix.  If, instead, you get `C3A2E282ACE2809C`, then you have a "double encoding", and it takes a different fix.

Answer these questions:

- Were the bytes you in the client are correctly encoded in utf8?  They probably were.
- Did you connected with the default `SET NAMES latin1` (or `set_charset('latin1')` or ...)?  (It needed to be `utf8`; but simply changing it won't suffice.)
- Is the column in the table was declared `CHARACTER SET latin1`.  (Or possibly it was inherited from the table/database.)  It should have been `utf8`.  There are multiple ways of changing it; using the wrong method will only make things worse.

Plan A:  Start over with the correct connection parameter and table definition.

Plan B:  Answer the above questions, and I will help you fix the mess.

Comment: Actually I didn't get either E28093 or C3A2E282ACE2809C. But here are the answers:

1) Yes, the bytes in the client side are UTF-8.
2) Yes, I connected with the default.
3) The table has char set of latin1.

Comment: What hex did you get?

Comment: The symbol â€“ is actually in a middle of a sentence so it's difficult to say how it was converted. 

What I did now was that I fixed the problem manually to the corrupted rows and fixed the code so that in the future the `–` symbol will get converted to `&ndash;` before inserting to the database. Thanks for help!