# php - data with particular character cannot be saved to the database

Tags: php, mysql, database, phpmyadmin, cpanel

please help me, I don't know how to explain the problem, I made the crud program to ensure that the problem is not in the program, the program can not store data with a particular character, for more details please see my video. thank you so so so much for your helping

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FN1rW8d_fIk&feature=youtu.be

Comment: What is that particular character?

Comment: @Shubhranshu for example """", >> <<, ||||, and sometimes when i use ckeditor, a-z also cannot be saved. im tired

Comment: You have to perform encoding, This may help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10113355/correct-php-method-to-store-special-chars-in-mysql-db

Comment: thank you beforely @Shubhranshu, but i was change all tables and my database to use utf8_unicode_ci, but still doesn't work :(

Comment: @DeniSetiawan do you want to escape those chars or do you want to store in db?

Comment: mysql_escape_string

Comment: @mwweb , i want all character store in db

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll show you a ex. 
mysql_query("update categorys set cateTitle='$catename' where cateID=$id");

Now $catename is: "James" "Smith"
=> We have a query: 
mysql_query("update categorys set cateTitle='"James" "Smith"' where cateID=$id"); See that? Can not put "" in to ''

Now you must edit query like this:
mysql_query("update categorys set cateTitle='/"James/" /"Smith/"' where cateID=$id");

SOLUTION:
You must put "/" forward charater so use this function:
mysql_escape_string($catename);

Comment: and how if i use yii is my php framework, there is not using query because have crud :(