# How to prevent MySQL sleep injections?

Tags: php, mysql, sql-injection

Recently one hacker tried to slow my website using sleep injection. Although we are using precautions like `mysql_real_escape_string()` to cover most of vulnerable inputs. We are passing id of the product through query string and it makes the command as:

```
$id = mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['id']);
$qry = "Select * from products where id = ".$id;
```

but hacker tried to provide input as

```
?id=3 and sleep(4)
```

and query becomes

```
Select * from products where id = 3 and sleep(4);
```

Although there are some possible solutions like

1. Check if the product id is numeric or not
2. Remove word sleep from input using some customized function

Is there any other method to stop this? What is the best method to prevent sleep injections?

Comment: Are you aware that `mysql_` functions are deprecated and you should not be using them?

Comment: [Parameter binding](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php) will prevent this

Comment: use mysqli_ instead mysql_

Comment: Aye, look at prepared statements to not just prevent 'sleep injection' (which I haven't heard of), bur all types of SQL injection.

Comment: +1 Best question I have read today.

Comment: Actually this is an old website and using 5.3. I think mysql_ functions has been deprecated for latest versions only

Comment: [The Great Escapism (Or: What You Need To Know To Work With Text Within Text)](http://kunststube.net/escapism/)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to prevent SQL injection in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: Actually, the attacker might not have wanted to slow down your website, but read all content of your database using a time-based blind query attack. The trick is that he can try to guess byte by byte, by using something like AND <some comparison> == "A" AND SLEEP(5) - if the page takes +5sec then the first assumption was TRUE. It is amazing how the whole database can be read like this (even if slow).

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You are not escaping correctly. `mysql_real_escape_string` is for escaping SQL *string* syntax correctly, but you are simply embedding the value as bare value, not as SQL string. You need:

```
$qry = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE id = '$id'";
```

Note the quotes around the id in the query.

If the id is numeric though, casting to a number would be more sensible:

```
$id = (int)$_GET['id'];
```

Comment: +1 For pointing out the proper use of `mysql_real_escape_string`.

Comment: @deceze : Thanks for the answer. I had accepted it because it's first part means proper use of     mysql_real_escape_string() is more relative and more quick answer of my question.

Comment: It's worth adding that `mysql_*` functions are deprecated and should not be used anymore.

Comment: also its very important to note, that the query requires single quotes to work properly. in case you use double quotes within the query string to sorround the value will render {mysql_real_escape_string()} useless!

Comment: This solves the purpose . However  what to put incase of string(non-int value) $str = $_GET['str'];

Answer (score 11):

The best method to prevent SQL injections is to use current technology. The MySQL `mysql_` family of functions is deprecated and will be removed from PHP in a future revision.

You should use prepared statements with either MySQLi or PDO instead.

These technologies use prepared statements and parameterized queries. SQL statements are parsed by the database server separately from any parameters. It is impossible for an attacker to inject malicious SQL.

You basically have two options to achieve this:

1. [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php):

   ```
   $stmt = $dbConnection->prepare('SELECT * FROM table WHERE name = ?');
   $stmt->bind_param('s', $name);
   $stmt->execute();
   $result = $stmt->get_result();
   while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
       // do something with $row
   }
   ```
2. [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php):

   ```
   $stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM table WHERE name = :name');
   $stmt->execute(array(':name' => $name));
   foreach ($stmt as $row) {
       // do something with $row
   }
   ```

What happens is that the SQL statement you pass to `prepare` is parsed and compiled by the database server. By specifying parameters (either a `?` or a named parameter like `:name`) you tell the database engine what you want to filter on. Then when you call `execute` the prepared statement is combined with the parameter values you specify.

The important thing here is that the parameter values are combined with the compiled statement, not a SQL string. SQL injection works by tricking the script into including malicious strings when it creates SQL to send to the database. So by sending the actual SQL separately from the parameters you limit the risk of ending up with something you didn't intend. Any parameters you send when using a prepared statement will just be treated as strings (although the database engine may do some optimization so parameters may end up as numbers too, of course).

Comment: The real question is, "Why bother?" Filtering is how we did this in the past, but times change, and we've moved on.

Comment: I revised my answer to explain why filtering is pointless with a prepared statement.

Comment: That's great, especially the part that says, "...and is much harder to pull off. AFAIK, you almost never see real 2nd order attacks, as it usually easier to social-engineer your way in." And then the comment, "If ALL your queries are parametrized, you're also protected against 2nd order injection. 1st order injection is forgetting that user data is untrustworthy. 2nd order injection is forgetting that database data is untrustworthy (because it came from the user originally)." That puts a cherry on it, don't you think?

Comment: Hey folks, Gordon is absolutely right. If you think escaping data for SQL is simply a security measure, then you are in for quite a surprise. Don't escape data for something until you use it in the context it should be escaped for. Otherwise, you are just making a mess of your data! Also, second order attacks should never be possible if you build your system right and use prepared queries.  You may think it isn't a problem... but it is. Even if you don't see it as a security problem, remember that a simple quote mark in a field will screw you up later. Maybe not malicious, but broken at least.

Comment: @Gordon Freeman : Your answer is more relevant for future use because i can't convert whole website to use PDO statements where it's not running on latest version. But thank you so much for such a good answer. Unfortunately, I can't accept more than one answers.

Answer (score 2):

This is wrong question to ask.

"**How to prevent mysql injections?**" it has to be. Sleep or not sleep - it doesn't matter.

And there are **plenty** of answers on this question already

- if you want a canonical one, then [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/285587)
- if you want to *understand*, how it works, [here I explained it in details](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2995163/285587)